# In-App Billing in Android. The exact way?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I've been working on implementing an in-app billing in Android for the app I'm building. The base app would be free and the in-app apps would come at a price.

I have followed the implementation method that has been documented in the Android Developers website. But still, it says that I can access the app I have created in the Android Market when in unpublished mode on the device, that has the test app. But this doesn't seem to work.

**My Current Progress**
I am able to call the Billing Service from my app for in-app billing successfully. But the reply says that "Error: Item not found"
The app I'm requesting from my base app is available in the android market in unpublished state. With two in-app apps in it.

**My Question**

1. I have mentioned the Item ID as com.karthik in the app. Is this correct in the first place? Or Should I call something like com.karthik.item.inapp1?
2. What change should I make in the Android Market? I have added another email ID as a tester's email ID in the market. And I'm testing this app on the device using this.

Kindly help me out!

**P.S.:** I have checked the other similar questions in the forum. But they aren't helping me!

Comment: Added a bug fix to Dungeons.java, and explained some misleading errors in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010642/android-in-app-billing-custom-sku-purchase-gives-error-item-not-found/13634414#13634414

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's the checklist:

1. [Sign](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/index.html) the .apk in release mode.
2. [Upload](http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=113469) the .apk as an "unpublished draft" to Google Play.
3. Upload a [products list](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-list-setup) for your draft app.
4. Make sure to **publish your items**, but **NOT your app**.
5. [Install](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html#RunningOnDevice) the release mode .apk to the device
6. Run app using a [test account](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-setup)
7. Purchase items in-app

Comment: Is the factory reset really necessary to use the test account?

Comment: You can not use your publisher account, the primary account on the phone needs to be a test account.

Comment: @DavidYKay You are right I also following the same steps as you mention i had sign the app,then make product list But it Doesn,t show me the product list which i had made.Why So ?can you help me to solve this problem. Thanks...

Comment: Hi Amandeep, you should move your question into another thread, but it's probably because you need to create your item list **on the device**. Publishing items in Google Play/Android Market only enables the IDs. The client doesn't download that list.

Answer (score 2):

I am testing a similar app (free with in-app billing), and I have to **publish the items**, although the app is still unpublished.

Comment: Ya! I got it through! There was a problem with the accounts that were used to test the in-app billing!

Answer (score 0):

1. I changed the public key to one in my dev console (public key)
2. Also changed the code as per above suggestion

On doing both above in-app billing worked.