# Android in-app billing: custom sku purchase gives "Error - item not found"

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to test in-app billing using my own sku/product ID "upgrade_to_premium". As I have seen recommended here, I am using the Dungeons sample app. I've added a "new CatalogEntry("upgrade_to_premium", R.string.upgrade_to_premium, Managed.MANAGED)" to the CatalogEntry[] array in Dungeons.java. In Const.java, DEBUG is set to TRUE.

I have uploaded my release-signed .apk to my Developer Console and activated it, and installed this same .apk to my device with adb.

I have entered an in-app product of the same name in the Dev Console, and published it.

I am logged into my phone not with my developer account but with a test Google account registered with my Developer Console. This account has associated credit card information; I am able to buy music with it.

My device is running Gingerbread, with the latest Google Play upgrade.

Upon starting the newly-installed application on my phone, I observe in LogCat the expected RestoreTransactions call, but it returns RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR. (Not a good start? I suppose not, but the five different *documented* possible causes for this error do not apply here, and who knows how many undocumented there are.) Then I try to purchase my custom sku upgrade_to_premium, but I get an alert dialog entitled "Error" with the message "Item not found", twice in succession, just about the time when it normally would be displaying the Market (Play) UI with VISA info. Interestingly, I observe a similar error when trying a Market URL containing an invalid (i.e. unpublished) package name. Is the unpublished draft that I uploaded what is not being found? Is my custom sku not being found? It's hard to tell from the vague error messages. Anyone have any clues? Thanks.

Here's the LogCat output:

```
06-13 00:08:31.858: D/Finsky(589): [1] 5.onFinished: Installation state replication    succeeded.
06-13 00:08:43.729: I/ActivityManager(109): Starting: Intent {  act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000  cmp=com.augmentedmind.dungeons/.Dungeons } from pid 196
6-13 00:08:43.795: I/ActivityManager(109): Start proc com.augmentedmind.dungeons for activity com.augmentedmind.dungeons/.Dungeons: pid=1247 uid=10054 gids={}
06-13 00:08:44.198: D/BillingService(1247): CheckBillingSupported
06-13 00:08:44.198: I/BillingService(1247): binding to Market billing service
06-13 00:08:44.213: D/BillingService(1247): CheckBillingSupported
06-13 00:08:44.213: I/BillingService(1247): binding to Market billing service
06-13 00:08:44.221: D/BillingService(1247): Billing service connected
06-13 00:08:44.225: D/BillingService(1247): CheckBillingSupported
06-13 00:08:44.237: D/Finsky(589): [26] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount:  com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:08:44.241: I/BillingService(1247): CheckBillingSupported response code: RESULT_OK
06-13 00:08:44.241: I/Dungeons(1247): supported: true
06-13 00:08:44.241: D/BillingService(1247): RestoreTransactions
06-13 00:08:44.245: D/Finsky(589): [8] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:08:44.249: D/Finsky(589): [8] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:08:44.260: I/ElegantRequestDirector(589): I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request: The target server failed to respond
06-13 00:08:44.260: E/BillingService(1247): restoreTransactions received RESULT_OK
06-13 00:08:44.260: D/BillingService(1247): request id: 2247584787757221561
06-13 00:08:44.260: I/ElegantRequestDirector(589): Retrying request
06-13 00:08:44.268: D/BillingService(1247): request id: -1
06-13 00:08:44.268: D/BillingService(1247): CheckBillingSupported
06-13 00:08:44.272: D/Finsky(589): [7] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:08:44.272: I/BillingService(1247): CheckBillingSupported response code: RESULT_OK
06-13 00:08:44.272: I/Dungeons(1247): supported: true
06-13 00:08:44.272: D/BillingService(1247): request id: -1
06-13 00:08:44.346: I/ActivityManager(109): Displayed com.augmentedmind.dungeons/.Dungeons: +556ms
06-13 00:08:44.729: D/Finsky(589): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR for request 2247584787757221561 to com.augmentedmind.dungeons.
06-13 00:08:44.741: I/BillingService(1247): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
06-13 00:08:44.741: D/BillingService(1247): RestoreTransactions: RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR
06-13 00:08:44.741: D/Dungeons(1247): RestoreTransactions error: RESULT_DEVELOPER_ERROR
06-13 00:09:28.049: D/Dungeons(1247): buying: Upgrade app to premium sku: upgrade_to_premium
06-13 00:09:28.053: D/BillingService(1247): RequestPurchase
06-13 00:09:28.092: D/Finsky(589): [26] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:09:28.096: D/Finsky(589): [26] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:09:28.100: I/ActivityManager(109): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity (has extras) } from pid -1
06-13 00:09:28.104: D/BillingService(1247): request id: 137676918944123250
06-13 00:09:28.104: D/BillingService(1247): RequestPurchase
06-13 00:09:28.108: D/Finsky(589): [27] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:09:28.112: D/Finsky(589): [27] MarketBillingService.getPreferredAccount: com.augmentedmind.dungeons: Account from first account.
06-13 00:09:28.112: I/ActivityManager(109): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cmp=com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity (has extras) } from pid -1
06-13 00:09:28.116: D/BillingService(1247): request id: 5138873787070031749
06-13 00:09:28.174: D/Finsky(589): [1] SelfUpdateScheduler.checkForSelfUpdate: Skipping self-update. Local Version [8011019] >= Server Version [0]
06-13 00:09:28.381: I/ActivityManager(109): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity: +262ms
06-13 00:09:28.413: E/Volley(589): [13] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=subs:com.augmentedmind.dungeons:upgrade_to_premium
06-13 00:09:41.670: W/InputManagerService(109): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40796830
06-13 00:09:41.737: D/Finsky(589): [1] SelfUpdateScheduler.checkForSelfUpdate: Skipping self-update. Local Version [8011019] >= Server Version [0]
```

around this time I get a popup dialog on the device screen entitled "Error" with the message "Item not found", twice. Just about the time when it normally would be displaying the Market (Play) UI with VISA info.

```
06-13 00:09:41.881: D/Finsky(589): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_ERROR for request 5138873787070031749 to com.augmentedmind.dungeons.
06-13 00:09:41.889: I/BillingService(1247): handleCommand() action: com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
06-13 00:09:41.889: D/BillingService(1247): RequestPurchase: RESULT_ERROR
06-13 00:09:41.893: D/Finsky(589): [1] PendingNotificationsService.setMarketAlarm: Setting alarm for account=tester.android30@gmail.com, duration=120000
06-13 00:09:41.940: I/ActivityManager(109): Displayed com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.activities.IabActivity: +271ms
06-13 00:09:41.991: E/Volley(589): [14] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 500 for https://android.clients.google.com/fdfe/details?doc=inapp:com.augmentedmind.dungeons:upgrade_to_premium
06-13 00:09:45.600: W/InputManagerService(109): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407daea0
06-13 00:09:45.682: D/Finsky(589): [1] MarketBillingService.sendResponseCode: Sending response RESULT_ERROR for request 137676918944123250 to com.augmentedmind.dungeons.
06-13 00:09:45.690: D/Finsky(589): [1] PendingNotificationsService.setMarketAlarm: Setting alarm for account=tester.android30@gmail.com, duration=120000
06-13 00:09:45.698: I/BillingService(1247): handleCommand() action:       com.android.vending.billing.RESPONSE_CODE
06-13 00:09:45.698: D/BillingService(1247): RequestPurchase: RESULT_ERROR
06-13 00:09:45.698: D/Dungeons(1247): upgrade_to_premium: RESULT_ERROR
06-13 00:09:45.698: I/Dungeons(1247): purchase failed
```

P.S. I read somewhere that one "might have to wait an hour or so for it to get activated" but I sincerely hope this is not the case for unpublished draft uploads! Why would this sort of upload, which no user will ever see, be subject to a delay? ...I am starting to think that this is true, as by repeated upload/delete/re-upload of this *unpublished draft app* I have just hit an upload quota. As painful as in-app billing is to master, I don't need that extra annoyance. Not good, Google.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I've just been trying to get the new version of the in-app billing sample code to work, and am having the same (it seems) issue. I did have the previous sample code (v1) working (a month or so ago). Cheers.

Comment: James - the issue is solved - see below. By the way I am definitely using API v.1: in BillingRequest.makeRequestBundle() I am saying request.putInt(Consts.BILLING_REQUEST_API_VERSION, 1);

Comment: See this check list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054894/android-in-app-sandbox-setting-error-for-a-pirticular-gmail-id/35496587#35496587

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to publish the product (not the app) for this to work. And yes, you need to wait a bit. Presumably while your APK's state is replicated to all Google Play servers. It used to work right away about a year ago, but this is not the case any more. However, you don't need to upload and test *the same APK*, only the version and signature need to match. So, when you begin developing a new version, just bump the version in the manifest, export and upload a signed APK. Let it sit there while you develop and test. Then replace it with your final binary when publishing.

Comment: Correction: I _had_ published my in-app product. I've corrected the original question.

Comment: Is the test account the primary account of your test device? BTW, RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS doesn't work for draft apps, so the error is normal.

Comment: By the next day, I was able to buy a custom product ID from myself, using a test account for the buying of course. Looks like I will be able to release in the next couple of days.

Comment: Ah, thanks Nikolai, that was a sanity-saver. So we only need to upload once, then reload the signed apk to the device as often as necessary for our development.  I was also able to get the JSON back from RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS with the recent purchase in it. Looks like I will be able to release in the next couple of days.

Comment: When testing, can you mix debug/release? So upload release apk to google, and then test with a debug apk?

Comment: If mean testing the IAB flow, no.

Answer (score 0):

Set your public key in variable `base64EncodedPublicKey` in Security class.

and use signed apk to test in app billing.

Answer (score 0):

You should note there are some very misleading errors and dialogs displayed in the demo Dungeons.java:

--

If you are getting "Error: This version of the application is not configured for Market billing."

You must installed the *RELEASE* apk to your android *DEVICE* not emulator meaning:

- Exporting your APK and signing it
- Deleting any previous installation of your app on your device (even debug / developer versions!)
- Side loading the APK to your device, installing it, and running it.
- This also means debugging your released app is probably going to be without your debugger attached.  If your debugger is attached, do tell me how!

If you are getting "Error: Item not found", there's a decent chance there is nothing wrong.

Dungeons.java actually has a bug in it.  Let me explain:

```
/**
 * Called when a button is pressed.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mBuyButton) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "buying: " + mItemName + " sku: " + mSku);
        }

        if (mManagedType != Managed.SUBSCRIPTION &&
                 // ** The following line is bug when returns !true which is false, and then makes the if statement false
                !mBillingService.requestPurchase(mSku, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, mPayloadContents)) { 
            showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);

            // ** Which then ends up running this else if, meaning it will try to purchase a subscription
        } else if (!mBillingService.requestPurchase(mSku, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, mPayloadContents)) {
            // Note: mManagedType == Managed.SUBSCRIPTION
            showDialog(DIALOG_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
        }
    } else if (v == mEditPayloadButton) {
        showPayloadEditDialog();
    } else if (v == mEditSubscriptionsButton) {
        editSubscriptions();
    }
}
```

Rather it should be written like this:

```
/**
 * Called when a button is pressed.
 */
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == mBuyButton) {
        if (Consts.DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "buying: " + mItemName + " sku: " + mSku);
        }

        // We need this statement to evaluate to true on a Non-Subscription such as a Managed or Unmanaged Purchase
        if (mManagedType != Managed.SUBSCRIPTION) { 

                // If the following errors out, show an error dialog.  However, it should not make the previous if statement false
                if( !mBillingService.requestPurchase(mSku, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, mPayloadContents)) { 
                    showDialog(DIALOG_BILLING_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
                }

        } 

         // This if statement gets run accidentally without the bug fix, thus trying to buy your "SKU" as a "subscription", which is totally wrong!
        else if (!mBillingService.requestPurchase(mSku, Consts.ITEM_TYPE_SUBSCRIPTION, mPayloadContents)) { 
            // Note: mManagedType == Managed.SUBSCRIPTION
            showDialog(DIALOG_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_SUPPORTED_ID);
        }
    } else if (v == mEditPayloadButton) {
        showPayloadEditDialog();
    } else if (v == mEditSubscriptionsButton) {
        editSubscriptions();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Export your app as an APK file.
Upload the APK to Google Play.
Sideload the same APK to your test device.
Wait an hour or so for Google Play to update its servers.
Test the installed APK.