# Google in app billing sample app: "error item not found"

Tags: in-app-billing, google-play

I'm trying to setup the in app billing sample applicaiton.
I've uploaded it to google play as "unpublished"
I've setup the sword_001 item and published it.

Now I'm trying to buy the item from the sample app on my phone and it always says "item not found"

any ideas?

Comment: Added a bug fix to Dungeons.java, and explained some misleading errors in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010642/android-in-app-billing-custom-sku-purchase-gives-error-item-not-found/13634414#13634414

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you follow the steps provided here :
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html

then you should able to do in app billing. few thing i found was : 
1. You need to set up a test account and it is NOT your developer account 
2. Make sure you publish the in app product 
3. Third step is to wait for a while or longer for google to update their server

first your apps will return item not found, and if you wait, then they will change to your item is found but unavailable for purchase, and if you wait for another hour or so (i don't know what time exactly) then your product should be accessible.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much for letting me know there's a waiting period... Otherwise this would've killed me!

Comment: Yeah the info on a delay should be in the official docs. Took about 2 hours for item not found to end for me. Then it was another 2 hours before it stopped saying item unavailable and started working.

Comment: The documentation for In-App billing is, on the surface very good. But there are critical mistakes (such as the sample application not working without a fix from a post on stack overflow) and no mention of the above. I can only imagine thousands of developers banging their heads against a brick wall. It would only take a few tweaks to get the sample app working again, and fix documentation error. Get your finger out Google!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was just so simple:

- i've just set the item on Google Play from "not activated" to "activated"