# Android In-App Sandbox setting error for a particular Gmail ID

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing

My Project is in Plyatore beta. The project contains subscription as monthly and yearly. So I added a Sandbox settings with 8 Gmail id's for testing the subscription.Then I configure each Gmail id in device account settings, only two Id is getting purchase dialog. Remaining 6 Gmail id's are getting one error message as "the item you requested is not available for purchase".

Is anyone has the same problem occurred, or anyone has the solution please help me to fix the issue. The mail id is separated with a comma in the sandbox filed in Playstore account. Also, each mail id has a valid credit card info.

Answer (score 2):

Go to this

```
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.yourcompany.yourapp
```

you will find a button allow currently logged in google mail account become beta tester of your app.
Make sure you have upload an beta or alpha version of your app to google store.

Check list:

1. Did you upload your app as Alpha or Beta version app
2. Check if item that registered at Play store is same with what you used in your code.
3. Check your package name, and Keystore file you used to build .
4. Check if logged in gmail account is beta test account
5. Check if you purchase you item at Play store that allowed. 
   Eg: You enable your app at US store, but you logged in with China store account, you will not able buy item.
6. Check you apk version: if your app version is lower than version registered at Google console , you will not able buy item.

Comment: Currently I have a beta version and its enabled for 1000 users. But the problem is I am creating a signed build from the same version and install the apk directly (Not from Playstore testing).

Comment: Did you go to ↑ address and check if your gmail account is accepted test user ?

Comment: Is that mandatory for direct apk install? The Gmail id's are in the sandbox.

Comment: This is not working. I set a Gmail id from device account setting and sync all features. Then I Open the browser and enter my application play store path under testing. Enable "become a tester" and download the application. Now the Gmail id is marked as a tester. Then I install the apk directly in the device. Now it's getting the same error while purchasing.

Comment: See the checklist i just added to my answer. This not work just because your setting are not correct.

Comment: Yes I am following this steps. But my problem is only some gmail id's. Remaining Id's are working fine.