# How does the new applicationId in build.gradle work?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Google released version 0.11 of the Android Gradle plugin.

The release notes contains the following:

> One of the user visible changes in 0.11 is that we've deprecated the
>   packageName and packageNameSuffix settings, and have renamed them to
>   applicationId and applicationIdSuffix. The purpose of this is to make
>   it clear that this application id is decoupled from package
>   declarations in your manifest, and in particular, the R class and the
>   BuildConfig class, and all the implementation classes inside your app,
>   can be renamed and refactored freely; you just need to keep
>   applicationId the same. If you open your build.gradle file, lint is
>   highlighting these deprecated calls and offering quickfixes to update
>   them:

What exactly does this mean. How is the packagename in the build script decoupled from the one in the manifest?

Comment: It was already decoupled, the one in the script doesn't reference the one in the manifest. By renaming this in the build script this should become more clear

Comment: So where is the one in the buildscript ending up once the app is compiled?

Comment: Related reading in the official docs: [ApplicationId versus PackageName](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`package` specified in AndroidManifest.xml identify one application installed on the device. The name of the property itself is misleading because one may think that refactoring java classes may require renaming `package` property as well. `package` property can be any string respecting limitation described in javadoc.

Because this confusion Google guys decided to rename `package` to `applicationId`. However, this change apply to gradle file only. Changing manifest property name would break compatibility with previous versions, that's my guess.

So when you build your APK, gradle replaces manifest's `package` property value with `applicationId` value specified in gradle script.

If you would like to test it yourself. Just set `applicationId` with different value that your manifest's `package` and build APK. Then go to folder */build/intermediates/manifests/dev/debug* and open AndroidManifest.xml. You will find there `applicationId` value.

Comment: That is clear. The question is where is the applicationId stored, if not in my manifest files once the app is packaged as an apk?

Comment: I have updated entire answer including where applicationId is stored.

Comment: I would say that Manifest Merger is responsible for that http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger.

Comment: Just reference to the release that cause the change. Google has a good overview there http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio060released

Comment: @Skillachie http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: If application id from gradle gets copied as package then how is this decoupling. this link http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename says **At the same time, the R class you are importing in your code must stay the same at all time; your .java source files should not have to change when you are building the different versions of your app.** . So if app id is copied you still have to go in change the package name of R class and others.

Comment: Its decoupled because changing `applicationId` affects only `package` in AndroidManifest.xml, your java sources and R class are not changed.

Comment: Reference Android documentation about applicationId: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-app-module#set_the_application_id