# How to deal with various build types in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am moving my Android Studio project over to Xamarin.

Under Android Studio/Gradle, I can have multiple build types. For example, I can create alpha, beta, and release version of the same app:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        debuggable true
    }
    alpha {
        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
     }
}
```

Gradle lets me modify the application id suffix so that I can install all the variations side by side on the same device.

I noticed that Xamarin lets you specify the package name from Visual Studio --> Project --> Properties --> Android Manifest. However, I need the package name to be different for various build types. How can I achieve this? Regards.

Comment: I my answer below helped can you please mark it as correct? I appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio you can create more [Build Configurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx).

You could create three `Build Congurations` (release, beta, alpha).

In each `Build Configuration` you could change the `applicationId` of the `Android Application` to match what you want. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178007/how-does-the-new-applicationid-in-build-gradle-work) answer we can assume that `applicationId` is the same as the `package` name.

So, you could have 3 `manifests` and when you change the build config it will replace the correspondent `manifest` with the modified `package` name. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496476/how-can-i-conditionally-include-a-file-based-on-build-configuration-in-xcode) to learn how to this.

Comment: But it doesn't tell me how to do this in Xamarin

Comment: My answer relates to something that you can do in .csproj level, so it is for Xamarin and other .NET projects.