# Android package name

Tags: android, android-studio

What is the mean of  `applicationId` in `build.gradle`. and what is the difference between package name in manifest file and applicationId in `build.gradle`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html

Comment: https://blog.mindorks.com/android-package-name-vs-application-id-ad95b08815a6

Comment: Too old question. You should search on google at first. Should CLOSE this question. Kindly maintain SO Rule

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the new applicationId in build.gradle work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178007/how-does-the-new-applicationid-in-build-gradle-work)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the mean of **`applicationId`** in build.gradle

Every Android app has a unique application ID that looks like a Java package name, such as `com.nilu.myapp`. This ID uniquely identifies your app on the device and in Google Play Store. If you want to upload a new version of your app, the application ID (and the certificate you sign it with) must be the same as the original APK—if you change the application ID, Google Play Store treats the APK as a completely different app. So once you publish your app, you should never change the application ID.

Read more about  [**`applicationId`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html)

> what is the difference between package name in manifest file and applicationId in build.gradle

package specified in AndroidManifest.xml identify one application installed on the device

Read more from this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24242435/7666442)** and this also **[Package Name Vs Application ID](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/package-name-vs-application-id/)**

Comment: I was exactly writing this. Nice explanation and linking is good

Answer (score -2):

`applicationId` in `build.gradle` will overwrite the manifest file's package value. And in `build.gradle` file you can use `productFlavors` to define different flavors, and each flavor can have different `applicationId`.

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.myapp.free"
    }
    paid {
        applicationId "com.myapp.pro"
    }
}
```