# Android Flavors, ContentProviders, SyncAdapters and AccountManager

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-syncadapter, android-productflavors

I have defined a few flavors and buildTypes for my android app

```
productFlavors {
    X {
        applicationId = "com.x.xxxx"
    }
    Y {
        applicationId = "com.y.yyyy"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard_rules.txt'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
```

That does the job of creating different flavors/buildType combinations.

Now to make sure that `ContentProviders` works and I do not get a `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER]` error, I have changed the `android:authorities="${applicationId}"` and `AUTHORITY` references in code to `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`.

That makes the `ContentProvider` work fine i.e it does not throw an error when I install two different types on the same phone. It lets me install them.

Next step is where the error is. I use `SyncAdapter` and `AccountManager` to control a few things. I have modified the `ACCOUNT_TYPE` to use the `APPLICATION_ID`. Because of the issue with gradle not being able to use `${applicationId}` in non-manifest xml resource files, I have created a different directory structure for each flavor and copied the `syncadapter.xml` and `authenticator.xml` with corresponding `authority` and `account type` strings.

I have also tried the technique described in this blog - http://blog.jensdriller.com/android-gradle-workaround-for-missing-placeholder-support-in-resource-files/

And the top voted answers on [Using build types in Gradle to run same app that uses ContentProvider on one device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16777534/using-build-types-in-gradle-to-run-same-app-that-uses-contentprovider-on-one-dev) but things don't seem to work.

Anyone been able to get this to work recently?