# How to programmatically prevent "conflicting provider" message

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-build-flavors, android-variants, android-flavors

Can anybody tell me how I can install different builds for different flavors on one device without getting a "duplicate provider" error message neither in PlayStore nor in AndroidStudio?

I have different flavors for different countries in my app and it's annoying to always uninstall the app before installing another one.

I tried:

```
productFlavors {
    austria {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            // prevent "duplicate provider authority" message
            providerAuthority: "com.example.app.at",
        ]
    }
    germany {
        manifestPlaceholders = [
            // prevent "duplicate provider authority" message
            providerAuthority: "com.example.app.de",
        ]
    }
    //...
}
```

and in my AndroidManifest I added:

```
android:authorities="${providerAuthority}"
```

to my

```
<application/>
```

tag.
This doesn't solve my problem.

I don't use a ContentProvider so I also tried adding a Stub ContentProvider class to the project and declared android:authorities="${providerAuthority}" inside the

```
<provider/>
```

tag including the name of the Stub ContentProvider --> no success.
I would be very happy about some other ideas or corrections.

UPDATE:

the error message I get from Android Studio when trying to install the app on my device.

[image: this is the error message I get from Android Studio]

Comment: "I don't use a ContentProvider" -- then what specifically is giving you this exception? "and in my AndroidManifest I added" -- if you do not use a `ContentProvider`, where did you add this attribute? You might consider posting the entire stack trace of the installation exception, which should be showing up in LogCat.

Comment: android:authorities should be added to your provider tag, please clerify your question and post the relevent sections of your manifest.xm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I lied when I said I didn't have a provider. I just didn't use it any more. So the solution for my problem was here (or simply deleting the unused provider): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24850080/3734116

I finally realized it by having a look into my generated / merged AndroidManifest in build/intermediates/manifests/ where I could find the Manifests for all my flavors. There I saw that one provider always had the same authority.

Another problem could have also been (but didn't apply to me)

- [Application ID not populated in AndroidManifest for libraries](https://issuetracker.google.com/code/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=784)
- [Multiple apps using same authority provider name for AppMeasurementContentProvider](https://issuetracker.google.com/code/p/android/issues/detail?id=193567)