# How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, release, android-gradle-plugin

I would like to have my Gradle build to create a release signed apk file using Gradle.

I'm not sure if the code is correct or if I'm missing a parameter when doing `gradle build`?

This is some of the code in my `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts` file:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile(file("release.keystore"))
            storePassword("******")
            keyAlias("******")
            keyPassword("******")
        }
    }
}
```

The Gradle build finishes *SUCCESSFUL*, and in my `build/apk` folder I only see the `...-release-unsigned.apk` and `...-debug-unaligned.apk` files.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html?hl=en#secure-shared-keystore

Comment: sign with v1 (jar signature) or v2 (full apk signature) version from gradle file? solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943259/how-to-use-v1-jar-signature-or-v2-full-apk-signature-from-build-gradle-file/57946742#57946742

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61028214/5733853

Comment: Probably related: [Signing product flavors with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17040494/8583692)

Comment: `build.gradle.kts` solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61188101/1562087

Answer (score 575, accepted):

Easier way than previous answers:

Put this into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE={path to your keystore}
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=*****
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Modify your `app/build.gradle`, and add this inside the `android {` code block:

```
...    
signingConfigs {

   release {
       storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
       storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD

       // Optional, specify signing versions used
       v1SigningEnabled true
       v2SigningEnabled true
   }
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
....
```

Then you can run `gradle assembleRelease`

---

[Also see the reference for the `signingConfigs` Gradle DSL](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/SigningConfig)

Comment: Best method if you ask me. Saves nothing in my project folder/SVN and I can checkout 10 versions of my projects without having to worry about the keys.

Comment: If you're using gradlew on Windows, you need to be sure GRADLE_USER_HOME is defined as an environment variable to make this work. I set it to one directory above my project directory, and put my keystore there. The path to your keystore in gradle.properties should use forward slashes (/) or double backslashes (\\\), not Windows single backslashes. To create a keystore from the Windows command prompt, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore

Comment: Is the path relative to where the build.gradle file is located, or relative to the machines root directory?

Comment: @Prem, `file()` always assumes relative paths. Use `new File(path)` if you want it to be treated as absolute.

Comment: none of the variables, arguments, etc were recognized. anyone know why?

Comment: @cjayem13 my guess is your gradle home isn't setup correctly to your PATH

Comment: This worked for me and the simplest. In the gradle.properties specify storeFile relative to your module build.gradle like so RELEASE_STORE_FILE=../mykeystore. Dont add quotes else gradle mangles the path

Comment: It's the best approach, working in both Linux and Windows.

Comment: Hi, my Jenkins still cannot found this variable, any idea ?

Comment: in case you are using gradle-expiremental, look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898555/signing-android-apk-with-gradle-experimental0-2-0

Comment: Why would you put this in your home `.gradle` directory? Wouldn't that apply these settings to all of your Android projects instead of the specific project? What happens if you have two or more projects with two or more keystores?

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Yes this applies to all projects, which is helpful in many cases. Lot of people sign many apps with the same certificates. If you have multiple certificates, create a more variants with different prefixes.

Comment: What about flags V1 (Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature)? How turn on it?

Comment: @anunixercoder, this won't fly if your CI doesn't have these variables set. The answer from Igor Ganapolsky does though, check it out!

Comment: Please note that the `build.gradle` lines showed here are to be put inside the `android{}` part, not on the top level.

Comment: As I already have these passwords set on my `android.signingConfigs.relase`on build.gradle,
I chose to just add `signingConfig signingConfigs.release` on my `buildTypes.release`

Comment: @NoumanCh fwiw I amended the answer with the v1/v2 signing configuration

Comment: For me I had to do ./gradlew assembleRelease instead of using the gradle executable.

Comment: This is very close, but your CI builds will fail unless you add the if statements from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25391891/1655478

Answer (score 287):

I managed to solve it adding this code, and building with `gradle build`:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("release.keystore")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "******"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

This generates a signed release apk file.

Comment: Is there a way to make it prompt me for the passwords? Or other suggestions to keep passwords out of my git repos?

Comment: I edit my build.gradle to look like yours but running "Built > Generate signed APK... " still gives my that dialog("See the Gradle User Guide for more info." etc.) and no APK.

Comment: @Semanticer Execute `gradle build` or `gradlew build` in Terminal/Prompt command

Comment: @user672009 you can put passwords in a properties file and exclude it from repos with .gitignore.  You can see this link.https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/6856974

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti That still leaves an incomplete repository. A better way would be to create a skeleton signing.properties and after committing issuing "git update-index --assume-unchanged signing.properties". However that prevents futura edits from being committed. Something like the first option sdqali suggests seems even better.

Comment: @user672009 You are right. I've improved the script with a check if file exist to prevent incomplete repository.

Comment: But in case the file doesn't exists the user is left with a message about a missing file of which he has no idea about how to create. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @user672009 you can add a template file (I see signing.properties.template in many projects in last days). You can also improve the script with an alert with println 'signing.properties not found'. (I updated my gist).

Comment: Does zip alignment (zipalign) occur as well ?

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  I'm still unable to build signed apk files ("blah.apk is not signed.  Please configure..." error message still pops up).

Comment: What about flags V1 (Jar Signature) and V2 (Full APK Signature)? How turn on it?

Comment: Make sure you have the signingConfigs block ABOVE the buildTypes block in your file.

Comment: and then I can just go and 'Build -> Build Bundle/APk -> ...' (instead of 'Generate singed Bundle/APK') for release version ???

Comment: @user672009 this also helps. 
This works with bundle ? Google playstore request this

Answer (score 73):

Note that @sdqali's script will (at least when using Gradle 1.6) ask for the password
anytime you invoke *any* gradle task. Since you only need it when doing `gradle assembleRelease` (or similar), you could use the following trick:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // We can leave these in environment variables
            storeFile file(System.getenv("KEYSTORE"))
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")

            // These two lines make gradle believe that the signingConfigs
            // section is complete. Without them, tasks like installRelease
            // will not be available!
            storePassword "notYourRealPassword"
            keyPassword "notYourRealPassword"
        }
    }
    ...
}

task askForPasswords << {
    // Must create String because System.readPassword() returns char[]
    // (and assigning that below fails silently)
    def storePw = new String(System.console().readPassword("Keystore password: "))
    def keyPw  = new String(System.console().readPassword("Key password: "))

    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePw
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPw
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { theTask -> 
    if (theTask.name.equals("packageRelease")) {
        theTask.dependsOn "askForPasswords"
    }
}
```

Note that I also had to add the following (under android) to make it work:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Comment: After implementing this, `installRelease` disappeared from the list of tasks... Why?

Comment: @caspase Wish I had taken your comment about that fake "storePassword" and "keyPassword" more seriously. Without initialising these properties ("" for example) the signed *-release.apk is not created, no error is displayed and your are left completely puzzled with just the *-release-unsigned.apk in your PROJECT_NAME/build/apk/ directory. Man... :/

Comment: Thanks for the note about adding signingConfig under buildTypes -> Release. That solved automated signing for me!

Comment: I made a simple gradle plugin that asks for passwords when building release apk (using mathod described in this post, but you will not need to define fake storePassword & keyPassword). It is also available in maven central. https://github.com/alexvasilkov/AndroidGradleSignPlugin

Comment: This is great. Beware that the environment variable `KEYSTORE` needs to be defined even for debug builds and for "gradle sync" inside Android Studio, otherwise it'll give an error about path being null.

Comment: If running from GUI and `System.console()` is not available, try something like:
`def storePw = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/libexec/openssh/ssh-askpass Keystore Password").getInputStream()).useDelimiter("\\n").next()`

Comment: Other solution is `def storePw = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()` but the disadvantage is that password is visible on screen.

Comment: This was my favorite solution until Gradle 5 started ignoring my attempts to override `android.signingConfigs.release` values. If this solution fails for you, you can try to stay with Gradle 4 until another solution is found.

Answer (score 68):

If you want to avoid hardcoding your keystore & password in **build.gradle**, you can use a properties file as explained here: [HANDLING SIGNING CONFIGS WITH GRADLE](https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/)

Basically:

1) create a myproject.properties file at **/home/[username]/.signing** with such contents:

```
keystore=[path to]\release.keystore
keystore.password=*********
keyAlias=***********
keyPassword=********
```

2) create a gradle.properties file (perhaps at the root of your project directory) with the contents:

```
MyProject.properties=/home/[username]/.signing/myproject.properties
```

3) refer to it in your **build.gradle** like this:

```
    if(project.hasProperty("MyProject.properties")
        && new File(project.property("MyProject.properties")).exists()) {

    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(file(project.property("MyProject.properties"))))

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(props['keystore'])
            storePassword props['keystore.password']
            keyAlias props['keyAlias']
            keyPassword props['keyPassword']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you. This code must be added before the buildTypes {} section and the section must declare the signingConfig signingConfigs.release as normal.

Comment: Finally I found a solution for this problem. The only thing that really helped me out! This sould be the accepted answer ...

Comment: How to use this in build.gradle file?

Answer (score 50):

### Automatic app signing with Gradle when using git

It's amazing how many convoluted ways there are for doing this. Here is my own way, where I try to adhere to Googles own [recommendation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html). However, their explanation is not fully clear, so I will describe the procedure for Linux in detail.

---

#### Description:

The default [Google instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for automatically signing an app 
during the build, without keeping the passwords and signature files 
in your app development (GIT) path, is rather obscure. Here are the 
clarified step-by-step instructions how to do so.

#### Initial assumptions:

You have an app called "MyApp" in a directory given by the following path:
`$HOME/projects/mydev/MyApp`. However, the MyApp directory is used and 
controlled with GIT.

[image]

#### Problem

We obviously don't want to have our signature or password files anywhere in
the GIT controlled directory, even if we are very able to use `.gitignore` etc, it is still too risky and easy to make a mistake. So we want our keystore and signature files outside.

#### Solution

We need to do three (3) things:

1. Create a password file to be used by Android Studio
2. Create signature key file
3. Edit the module `build.gradle` file to use (1) and (2).

For this example we name the two files:

1. `keystore.properties`
2. `MyApp-release-key.jks`

We can put both of these files here:

```
cd $HOME/projects/mydev/
```

#### (1) Create the keystore password file

The first file contain the clear text passwords used in; and paths to the release-key file in (2). Start with filling this out, as it will make a copy paste operation easier for the next step.

```
cd $HOME/projects/mydev/
```

Edit `keystore.properties` so that it's content is:

```
storePassword=myStorePassword
keyPassword=mykeyPassword
keyAlias=myKeyAlias
storeFile=myStoreFileLocation
```

The only tricky part here, is the `myStoreFileLocation`. This is the path **as seen from** the module `build.gradle` file during the build. This usually means a path similar and relative to: `$HOME/projects/mydev/MyApp/app/build.gradle`. So in order to point to the `MyApp-release-key.jks`
file, what we need to put here is:

`../../../MyApp-release-key.jks`

Here, we also chose the "myapp" alias for the key. Then the final file should look:

```
storePassword=myStorePassword
keyPassword=mykeyPassword
keyAlias=myapp
storeFile=../../../MyApp-release-key.jks
```

#### (2) Create the signature file

The second file is automatically generated when you create the signature key. 
If you have no other apps and this is your only keystore, then create the file with:

```
cd $HOME/projects/mydev/
keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore MyApp-release-key.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias myapp
```

This will ask you for two passwords and a bunch of info. (Same stuff as in Android Studio.) Now copy/paste your previously chosen passwords.

#### (3) Edit your module `gradle.build` file to use the above

The following parts need to be present in your app/module's Gradle build file. First, add the following lines **outside** and **before** your `android {}` block.

```
//def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("$HOME/.android/keystore.properties")
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("../../keystore.properties")
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
```

Then, **inside** the `android {}` block, add:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig { ... }
    signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
                storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
                storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
            }
        }
    // Tell Gradle to sign your APK
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now from shell, you can re-build your app with:

```
cd $HOME/projects/mydev/MyApp/app/
./gradlew clean build
```

This should generate a properly signed app that can be used in Google Play.

---

**UPDATE:** 2019-04-02

More recent versions of `keytool` and *something* is telling you that you should use a **PKCS12** based keyfile instead of the original/default as I use above. *They* then go on telling you you should convert to the new open PKCS12 format. However, it seem that the Android development tools are not quite ready for this yet, because if you do, you will get the following weird errors:

> `com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException:` Failed to read key
>   XXX from store "F:\XXX\XXX.jks": Get Key failed: Given final block not
>   properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during
>   decryption.

So don't use a converted key!

Comment: Is signingConfigs saved inside the apk and then it can be decompiled by any user to get passwords or it doens't appear in the apk?

Comment: Works like charm. Thank-you this should be the accepted Answer

Comment: What if you only want the keystore and passwords on a build server? With the solution above every developer in the team needs to have the keystore on their local machine. Otherwise the Gradle project sync will fail: keystore.properties (No such file or directory).

Comment: You can commit a dummy `keystore.properties` file to source control, so builds work on dev machines. I've described a build server setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876003/843660).

Comment: A note on your last update about `keytool` generating a PKCS12 keystore: you can pass `-storetype JKS` in the `keytool` command to set the keystore type to JKS which is needed by the Android tooling.

Comment: I made one change to this, which is to place the keystore.properties file in the same folder as the keystore (.jks) file.
This way, I know right from build.gradle, when hitting sync now..., if the path specified for the properties file is correct. In the properties file, then, I don't need to specify the path to the .jks file because both the properties file and keystore file are in the same folder, as mentioned above.

Answer (score 37):

Like @Destil said but allow others who don't have the key to build:
Easier way than previous answers:

Put this into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE={path to your keystore}
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=*****
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Modify your `build.gradle` like this:

```
...    
if(project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
    signingConfigs {    
       release {
           storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
           storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
           keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
           keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
       }
    }
}

buildTypes {
    if(project.hasProperty("RELEASE_STORE_FILE")) {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
....
```

Then you can run `gradle assembleRelease`
OR
`gradle build`

Comment: How to set path in windows: path to your keystore

Comment: storeFile file("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\yyyy\\mykey.jks") is it right?

Comment: That if statement is vital unless you want your CI builds to fail.

Answer (score 37):

If you have the keystore file already, it can be as simple as adding a few parameters to your build command:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease \
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.file=$KEYFILE \
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.store.password=$STORE_PASSWORD \
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.alias=$KEY_ALIAS \
 -Pandroid.injected.signing.key.password=$KEY_PASSWORD
```

No permanent changes to your Android project necessary.

Source: http://www.tinmith.net/wayne/blog/2014/08/gradle-sign-command-line.htm

Comment: this solution is very elegant. thank you friend

Answer (score 28):

(In reply to [user672009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle#comment27871848_18329835) above.)

An even easier solution, if you want to keep your passwords out of a git repository; yet, want to include your build.gradle in it, that even works great with product flavors, is to create a separate gradle file. Let's call it 'signing.gradle' (include it in your .gitignore). Just as if it were your build.gradle file minus everything not related to signing in it.

```
android {
    signingConfigs { 
        flavor1 {
            storeFile file("..")
            storePassword ".."
            keyAlias ".."
            keyPassword ".."
        }
        flavor2 {
            storeFile file("..")
            storePassword ".."
            keyAlias ".."
            keyPassword ".."
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your build.gradle file include this line right underneath "apply plugin: 'android'"

```
 apply from: 'signing.gradle'
```

If you don't have or use multiple flavors, rename "flavor1" to "release" above, and you should be finished. If you are using flavors continue.

Finally link your flavors to its correct signingConfig in your build.gradle file and you should be finished.

```
  ...

  productFlavors {

      flavor1 {
          ...
          signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor1
      }

      flavor2 {
          ...
          signingConfig signingConfigs.flavor2
      }
  }

  ...
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific. I can't make it run: "cannot resolve symbol signingConfig".

Comment: If I include 'signing.gradle' in the build.gradle - I am forced to have one in git repository (else I get error 'signing.gradle does not exist'). And if I put the 'signing.gradle' in git, it defeats the purpose. How can I make inclusion of signing.gradle optional ?

Answer (score 19):

This is a reply to [user672009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle#comment27871848_18329835) and addition to [sdqali's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130098/1408535) (his code will crash on building debug version by IDE's "Run" button):

You can use the following code:

```
final Console console = System.console();
if (console != null) {

    // Building from console 
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(console.readLine("Enter keystore path: "))
            storePassword console.readLine("Enter keystore password: ")
            keyAlias console.readLine("Enter alias key: ")
            keyPassword console.readLine("Enter key password: ")
        }
    }

} else {

    // Building from IDE's "Run" button
    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have some default values? My keystore is usually the same. The storePassword usually the same as keyPassword and the keyAlias usually the project name in lower case.

Comment: @user672009 you can always use Java code inside of the script.

Comment: you might want to use something like this: `keyPassword new String(console.readPassword("Enter key password: "))` to make sure your password is not displayed during input

Comment: This doesn't work anymore, see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1251

Answer (score 19):

If you build apk via command line like me then you can provide signing configuration as arguments.

Add this to your `build.gradle`

```
def getStore = { ->
    def result = project.hasProperty('storeFile') ? storeFile : "null"
    return result
}

def getStorePassword = { ->
    def result = project.hasProperty('storePassword') ? storePassword : ""
    return result
}

def getKeyAlias = { ->
    def result = project.hasProperty('keyAlias') ? keyAlias : ""
    return result
}

def getKeyPassword = { ->
    def result = project.hasProperty('keyPassword') ? keyPassword : ""
    return result
}
```

Make your `signingConfigs` like this

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(getStore())
        storePassword getStorePassword()
        keyAlias getKeyAlias()
        keyPassword getKeyPassword()
    }
}
```

Then you execute `gradlew` like this

```
./gradlew assembleRelease -PstoreFile="keystore.jks" -PstorePassword="password" -PkeyAlias="alias" -PkeyPassword="password"
```

Comment: Which is `build.gradle`? Top level? Please add more code

Comment: To clarify, this is `app/build.gradle` file I'm talking about.

Answer (score 17):

In newer Android Studio, there is a GUI way which is very easy and it populates Gradle file as well.

1. `File -> Project Structure`
2. `Module ->` Choose the main module ('app' or other custom name)
3. `Signing` tab -> Plus image to add new configuration
4. Fill data on the right side
5. OK and Gradle file is automatically created
6. You will manually have to add a line `signingConfig signingConfigs.NameOfYourConfig` inside `builtTypes{release{}}`

Images:

[image]

[image]

Two important(!) notes:

(EDIT 12/15)

1. To create signed APK, you'd have to open Terminal tab of Android Studio (the bottom of the main interface) and issue a command `./gradlew assembleRelease`
2. If you forgot `keyAlias` (what happens often to me), you will have to initiate `Build -> Generate Signed APK` to start the process and see the name of the Alias key.

Comment: This hardcodes your passwords into the `build.gradle` file, though, doesn't it?

Comment: The layout in Android Studio has changed. It's now `File` > `Project Structure` > `Modules(located in right pane)` > `app(located in center pane under Modules)` > `Signing Configs`

Answer (score 14):

### For Kotlin Script (build.gradle.kts)

You should not put your signing credentials directly in the *build.gradle.kts* file. Instead the credentials should come from a file not under version control.

Put a file *signing.properties* where the module specific *build.gradle.kts* is found. Don't forget to add it to your *.gitignore* file!

**signing.properties**

```
storeFilePath=/home/willi/example.keystore
storePassword=secret
keyPassword=secret
keyAlias=myReleaseSigningKey
```

**build.gradle.kts**

```
android {
    // ...
    signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            val properties = Properties().apply {
                load(File("signing.properties").reader())
            }
            storeFile = File(properties.getProperty("storeFilePath"))
            storePassword = properties.getProperty("storePassword")
            keyPassword = properties.getProperty("keyPassword")
            keyAlias = "release"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    File signFile = rootProject.file('sign/keystore.properties')
    if (signFile.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        properties.load(new FileInputStream(signFile))
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                storeFile rootProject.file(properties['keystore'])
                storePassword properties['storePassword']
                keyAlias properties['keyAlias']
                keyPassword properties['keyPassword']
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            zipAlign true
            proguardFile rootProject.file('proguard-rules.cfg')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            runProguard false
            zipAlign true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using Android Studio 0.5.1, Gradle 1.11, and Gradle plugin 0.9.

Comment: Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0

Answer (score 10):

You can also use **-P** command line option of gradle to help the signing. In your build.gradle, add singingConfigs like this:

```
signingConfigs {
   release {
       storeFile file("path/to/your/keystore")
       storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias "your.key.alias"
       keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
   }
}
```

Then call gradle build like this:

```
gradle -PRELEASE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=******* -PRELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=****** build
```

You can use -P to set storeFile and keyAlias if you prefer.

This is basically Destil's solution but with the command line options.

For more details on gradle properties, check the [gradle user guide](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties).

Answer (score 7):

Almost all platforms now offer some sort of keyring, so there is no reason to leave clear text passwords around.

I propose a simple solution that uses the [Python Keyring module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring) (mainly the companion console script `keyring`) and a minimal wrapper around Groovy `['do', 'something'].execute()` [feature](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Executing+External+Processes+From+Groovy):

```gradle
def execOutput= { args ->
    def proc = args.execute()
    proc.waitFor()
    def stdout = proc.in.text
    return stdout.trim()
}
```

Using this function, the `signingConfigs` section becomes:

```gradle
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("android.keystore")
        storePassword execOutput(["keyring", "get", "google-play", storeFile.name])
        keyAlias "com.example.app"
        keyPassword execOutput(["keyring", "get", "google-play", keyAlias])
    }
}
```

Before running `gradle assembleRelease` you have to set the passwords in your keyring, only once:

```bash
$ keyring set google-play android.keystore # will be prompted for the passwords
$ keyring set google-play com.example.app
```

Happy releases!

Answer (score 7):

@Destil's answer is good if you can reuse the same configuration across all projects. Alternatively, Android Studio comes with a `local.properties` file that can maybe be used instead, but it's supposedly IDE-generated and I can't find a way to extend it from within Android Studio.

This is a variation of [@jonbo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21494441/482758). That answer allows project specific settings but it comes with a bit of developer overhead. Specifically, significant boilerplate is required to move the `signingConfigs` definition into a separate file -- especially if you need to do so for multiple projects, which is a prime reason for picking this solution over Destil's. This can be somewhat alleviated by *also* including the line

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

in the credentials file, as this will allow IDE completion.

Finally, most solutions here do *not* allow building the project in debug mode -- which handles debug-signing automatically -- without providing a syntactically if not semantically valid `signingConfigs` definition. If you do not need to produce a release build from a given machine, this extra step can be seen as an unnecessary obstacle. On the other hand, it can be an aid against ignorant or lazy colleagues running debug builds in production.

This solution will allow debug builds without worrying about credentials at all, but it will require valid credentials to produce release builds, and it takes very little boilerplate. However, as a downside **it might encourage others to replace dummy values with real credentials** and there's no way to protect against that.

```
// app/build.gradle
// Define this structure in signing.gradle to enable release builds.
ext.signing = [
        storeFilePath : 'path/to/keystore',
        storePassword : 'keystore password',
        keyAlias      : 'key alias',
        keyPassword   : 'key password',
]

if (file('signing.gradle').exists()) {
    apply from: 'signing.gradle'
}

android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(project.signing.storeFilePath)
            storePassword project.signing.storePassword
            keyAlias project.signing.keyAlias
            keyPassword project.signing.keyPassword
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug { ... }
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a dummy property that serves purely to produce a syntactically valid build file. The values assigned to `ext.signing`'s properties are irrelevant as far as debug builds go. To enable release builds, copy `ext.signing` into `signing.gradle` and replace the dummy values with valid credentials.

```
// signing.gradle
ext.signing = [
        storeFilePath : 'real/keystore',
        storePassword : 'real keystore password',
        keyAlias : 'real key alias',
        keyPassword : 'real key password',
]
```

Of course, `signing.gradle` should be ignored by VCS.

Answer (score 6):

I had quite a lot of fun figuring this one out. Here is my walk-through.

A to Z walk-through on how to create a gradle build file in IntelliJ (v.13.1.4)
This walk-through assumes you know how to make a keystore file.
For this tutorial to work you will need your keystore file to be located in your app folder and you will need to have your zipalign.exe file to be located in 'SDK-ROOT\tools'. This file is usually found in 'SDK-ROOT\build-tools' and under this folder it will be in the highest api folder (alpha or beta I recommend the alpha version).

For those of you that wish to jump straight in here is the gradle build file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        playstore {
            keyAlias 'developers4u'
            keyPassword 'thisIsNotMyRealPassword'
            storeFile file('developers4u.keystore')
            storePassword 'realyItIsNot'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        assembleRelease {
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            zipAlign true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.playstore
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

You can build part of this build file (above) from menu option: File/Project Structure
From here select Facets and click 'Android-Gradle(App).
From here you will see tabs: 'Properties', 'Signing', 'Flavors', 'Build Types' and 'Dependencies' for this walk-through we will just be using 'Signing' and 'Build Types'.
Under 'Build Types' (in the name section) enter any name that you wish to identify your build type configuration and in the other 4 fields enter your keystore information (setting the keystore path the the one under your app folder).

Under the 'Build Types' enter the value 'assembleRelease' into the name field, 'Debuggable' should be set to false, 'Jni Debug Build' should be false, set 'Run Proguard' to true and 'Zip Align' to true. This will generate build file, but not as depicted above, you will have to add a few things to the build file afterwards. The ProGuard file location here will be set manually in the gradle build file. (as depicted above)

The DSL containers you will have to add afterwards are as follows:

```
android {
    ....
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    ....
}
```

You will also have to add:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

note this DSL container above('dependencies') should be at the bottom of the config file but not inside the android DSL container.
In order to build the dependencies container from the IntelliJ menu, select: File/Project Structure. From there select Facets again and then Android-Gradle(app). You will see the same 5 tabs as mentioned above. Select the 'Dependencies' tab and add the dependencies you require.

After all of this is done you should see a Gradle build file similar to the file at the top of this walk-through.
To build your signed zip aligned release you will need to open the Gradle tasks. You can get to this window by selecting View/Tool Windows/Gradle.
From here you can double Click 'assembleAssembleRelease. This should generate your deployable APK.

The potential problems that can occur when compiling your release are (but not limited to): Your Gradle build file being in the wrong place. There are two Gradle build files; one in your application root folder and another in the app folder under the application root. You must user the latter.

You may also have lint problems. (Note: Android Developer Studio is much better at spotting Lint problems than IntelliJ you will notice this when trying to generate an signed APK from the menu options)

To get around lint problems you will need to put the following DSL container inside the android container (at the top):

```
android {
        ....
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    ....
}
```

putting this inside your android DSL container will cause an error file to be generated in the build folder (directly under your app folder) the file name should be something like 'lint-results-release-fatal.html' this file will tell you the the class where the error occurred. Another file that will be generated is an XML file that contains the 'issue ID' associated with the lint error. The file name should be something like 'lint-results-release-fatal.xml'. Somewhere near the top of the file you will see a node 'issue' inside which you will see something similar to 'id="IDOfYourLintProblem"'

To correct this problem open the file in your project that was listed in the 'lint-results-assembleRelease-fatal.html' file and enter the following line of code in the Java Class file just above the class name: @SuppressLint("IDOfYourLintProblem"). You may have to import 'android.annotation.SuppressLint;'

So your java class file should appear like:

```
package com.WarwickWestonWright.developers4u.app.CandidateArea;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
... other imports

@SuppressLint("IDOfYourLintProblem")
public class SearchForJobsFragment extends Fragment {... rest of your class definition}
```

Note that suppressing lint errors is not always the best IDEA you may be better off to change your code that caused the lint errors.

Another problem that could potentially occur is if you have not set the environment variable for the Gradle HOME environment variable. This variable is named 'GRADLE_HOME' and should be set the the path of the gradle home directory, something like 'C:\gradle-1.12'
Sometimes you may also want to set the environment variable for 'ANDROID_HOME' set this to 'YOUR-SDK-Root\sdk'

After this is done return to the Gradle tasks window and double click the assembleAssembleRelease.

If all is successful you should be able to go to the folder app\build\apk and find your deployable APK file.

Comment: +1 for the effort and:
'lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }'

Answer (score 6):

Extending the answer by David Vavra,create a file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and add

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE=/path/to/.keystore
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=XXXXX
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXX
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=XXXXXXXXX
```

Then in build.gradle

```
  signingConfigs {
    release {
    }
  }

  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true

    }
  }

  // make this optional
  if ( project.hasProperty("RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS") ) {
    signingConfigs {
      release {
        storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
      }
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

### For Groovy (build.gradle)

You should not put your signing credentials directly in the *build.gradle* file. Instead the credentials should come from a file not under version control.

Put a file *signing.properties* where the module specific *build.gradle* is found. Don't forget to add it to your *.gitignore* file!

**signing.properties**

```
storeFilePath=/home/willi/example.keystore
storePassword=secret
keyPassword=secret
keyAlias=myReleaseSigningKey
```

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    // ...
    signingConfigs{
        release {
            def props = new Properties()

            def fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file('../signing.properties'))
            props.load(fileInputStream)
            fileInputStream.close()

            storeFile = file(props['storeFilePath'])
            storePassword = props['storePassword']
            keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
            keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It is 2019 and I need to sign APK with V1 (jar signature) or V2 (full APK signature). I googled "generate signed apk gradle" and it brought me here. So I am adding my original solution here.

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        ...
        v1SigningEnabled true
        v2SigningEnabled true
    }
}
```

My original question: [How to use V1 (Jar signature) or V2 (Full APK signature) from build.gradle file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943259/how-to-use-v1-jar-signature-or-v2-full-apk-signature-from-build-gradle-file/57946742#57946742)

Answer (score 4):

Yet another approach to the same problem. As it is not recommended to store any kind of credential within the source code, we decided to set the passwords for the key store and key alias in a separate properties file as follows:

```
key.store.password=[STORE PASSWORD]
key.alias.password=[KEY PASSWORD]
```

If you use git, you can create a text file called, for example, secure.properties. You should make sure to exclude it from your repository (if using git, adding it to the .gitignore file). Then, you would need to create a signing configuration, like some of the other answers indicate. The only difference is in how you would load the credentials:

```
android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        ...
        release {
            storeFile file('[PATH TO]/your_keystore_file.jks')
            keyAlias "your_key_alias"

            File propsFile = file("[PATH TO]/secure.properties");
            if (propsFile.exists()) {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))
                storePassword props.getProperty('key.store.password')
                keyPassword props.getProperty('key.alias.password')
            }
        }
        ...
    }

    buildTypes {
        ...
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            runProguard true
            proguardFile file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Never forget to assign the signingConfig to the release build type manually (for some reason I sometimes assume it will be used automatically). Also, it is not mandatory to enable proguard, but it is recommendable.

We like this approach better than using environment variables or requesting user input because it can be done from the IDE, by switching to the realease build type and running the app, rather than having to use the command line.

Comment: Gradle doesn't compile using this:

props = new Properties();

Cannot set the value of read-only property 'props'

Comment: You are right @m3n0R. I edited a line of my response to reflect the fix we had to introduce in our app so it would still compile using the latest versions of Gradle. Basically, props has to be declared as a local variable.

Comment: how would this be adoptable using cloud CI/CD tools....the /path/to/keystore and /path/to/secure.props is throwing me....thanks for this though.

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio
Go to **File -> Project Structure** or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S

See The Image

[image]

Click Ok

Then the signingConfigs will generate on your build.gradle file.

[image]

Comment: And this is exactly what you don't want to do. This way **all your passwords are in clear-text and part of your project**, and very easy to accidentally include, even in your distributed build.

Answer (score 4):

This is another answer for [Kotlin build scripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html) (build.gradle.**kts**).

It tries to read from *local.properties* file, falling back to the OS environment variables. It can be especially useful in CIs like GitHub Actions (you can create environment secrets in your repository settings).

Note that I'm using Kotlin 1.6.10 and Gradle 7.4.2 and Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 7.0.4.

```kotlin
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.configure.gradleLocalProperties
// ...

val environment = System.getenv()
fun getLocalProperty(key: String) = gradleLocalProperties(rootDir).getProperty(key)
fun String.toFile() = File(this)

android {
    signingConfigs {
        create("MySigningConfig") {
            keyAlias = getLocalProperty("signing.keyAlias") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS"] ?: error("Error!")
            storeFile = (getLocalProperty("signing.storeFile") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_FILE"] ?: error("Error!")).toFile()
            keyPassword = getLocalProperty("signing.keyPassword") ?: environment["SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD"] ?: error("Error!")
            storePassword = getLocalProperty("signing.storePassword") ?: environment["SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD"] ?: error("Error!")
            enableV1Signing = true
            enableV2Signing = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig = signingConfigs["MySigningConfig"]
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
}
```

As said, you can either have a *local.properties* file at the root of your project with values for the properties:

```
signing.keyAlias=My key
signing.keyPassword=zyxwvuts
signing.storePassword=abcdefgh
signing.storeFile=C\:\\Users\\Mahozad\\keystore.jks
```

... or you can set/create environment variables on your OS; for example to create an environment variable called `SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS` run:

- Windows Command Prompt: `setx SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS "My key"`
- Linux Terminal: `export SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS="My key"`

**NOTE**: As mentioned by other answers, do NOT add your *local.properties* file to your version control system (like Git), as it exposes your secret information like passwords etc. to the public (if it's a public repository).

#### Generate your APK with either of the 3 ways that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20927125/8583692) mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I had several issues that I put the following line in a wrong place:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        // We can leave these in environment variables
        storeFile file("d:\\Fejlesztés\\******.keystore")
        keyAlias "mykey"

        // These two lines make gradle believe that the signingConfigs
        // section is complete. Without them, tasks like installRelease
        // will not be available!
        storePassword "*****"
        keyPassword "******"
    }
}
```

Make sure that you put the signingConfigs parts inside the android section:

```
android
{
    ....
    signingConfigs {
        release {
          ...
        }
    }
}
```

instead of

```
android
{
    ....
}

signingConfigs {
   release {
        ...
   }
}
```

It is easy to make this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the other answers, you can also place your gradle.properties file in your own module folder, together with build.gradle, just in case your keystore is specific to one project.

Answer (score 1):

i am work in  Ubuntu14.04. 
vim ~/.bashrc  and add
export ANDROID_KEYSTORE=
export ANDROID_KEYALIAS=

and then in build.gradle set.

```
    final Console console = System.console();
if (console != null) {

    // Building from console
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv("KEYSTORE"))
            storePassword new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Enter keystore password: "))
            keyAlias System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Enter key password: "))
        }
    }

} else {

    // Building from IDE's "Run" button
    signingConfigs {
        release {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: IMHO that seems to be the best solution, but unfortunately [it stopped working on newer versions of Gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1251): `System.console()` returns `null`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to define a task that runs only on release builds.

```
android {
  ...
  signingConfigs {
     release {
        // We can leave these in environment variables
        storeFile file('nameOfKeystore.keystore')
        keyAlias 'nameOfKeyAlias'

        // These two lines make gradle believe that the signingConfigs
        // section is complete. Without them, tasks like installRelease
        // will not be available!
        storePassword "notYourRealPassword"
        keyPassword "notYourRealPassword"

     }
  }
  buildTypes {
     ...
     release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
     }
  }
  ...
}

task setupKeystore << {
final Console console = System.console();
if (console != null) {
    //def keyFile = console.readLine(“\nProject: “ + project.name + “Enter keystore path: "))
    //def keyAlias = console.readLine(“Project: “ + project.name + “Enter key alias: ")
        def storePw = new String(console.readPassword(“Project: “ + project.name + “. Enter keystore password: "))
        def keyPw  = new String(console.readPassword(“Project: “ + project.name + “.Enter keystore password: "))

    //android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(keyFile);
    //android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePw
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPw
}
}

//Validate t
def isReleaseConfig = gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any {it.contains('Release') }
if (isReleaseConfig) {
    setupKeystore.execute();
}
```

Comment: The following seems preferable to me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19130098/3664487 How do the two approaches compare?

Answer (score 1):

You can request passwords from the command line:

```
...

signingConfigs {
  if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any {it.contains('Release') }) {
    release {
      storeFile file("your.keystore")
      storePassword new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Enter keystore password: "))
      keyAlias "key-alias"
      keyPassword new String(System.console().readPassword("\n\$ Enter keys password: "))
    } 
  } else {
    //Here be dragons: unreachable else-branch forces Gradle to create
    //install...Release tasks.
    release {
      keyAlias 'dummy'
      keyPassword 'dummy'
      storeFile file('dummy')
      storePassword 'dummy'
    } 
  }
}

...

buildTypes {
  release {

    ...

    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }

  ...
}

...
```

The `if-then-else` block prevents requests for passwords when you're building a release. Although the `else` branch is unreachable, it tricks Gradle into creating an `install...Release` task.

**Backstory**. As noted by https://stackoverflow.com/a/19130098/3664487, "*Gradle scripts can prompt for user input using the System.console().readLine method*." Unfortunately, Gradle will always request a password, even when you're building a debug release (cf. [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle#comment36226293_19130098)). Fortunately, this can be overcome, as I have shown above.

Comment: My earlier answer ran into problems due to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897802/gradle-build-type-missing-in-android-project/. I have revised my answer to eliminate this problem.

Comment: @Haroon, it worked as of 24 Nov '15. The community can perhaps help with your problem, but you'll need to provide more details.

Comment: I like this solution since it avoids putting the password in clear text in a text file but System.console().readLine does not work in gradle due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487576/gradle-build-null-console-object) annoying issue.

Comment: @morpheus, I've never had a problem. The above is working for me.

Comment: I think you run the script from within a IDE. if the script is run from terminal you will see the error. but thanks for this answer. this is what i was looking for.

Comment: I'm running the script from the command-line. I'll be using it in the next few days, I'll double-check.

Comment: I can confirm that the script is still working for me. I can't see anything obvious that would preclude it from working for you. Perhaps 
`buildscript { repositories { jcenter() } dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0' } }`, `compileSdkVersion 23`, or `buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"`.

Comment: @morpheus please let me know whether the above comment helped and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user2768 I am surprised that the script works for you. Don't you run into the issue documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487576/gradle-build-null-console-object

Comment: @morpheus. No, I don't. Possibly because the problematic call `System.console().readLine()` does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my way to do it in React-Native using [react-native-config](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config) package.
Create a .env file:

```
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=[YOUR_PASSWORD]
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=[YOUR_PASSWORD]
```

note this should not be part of the version control.

in your `build.gradle`:

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword project.env.get('RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD')
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword project.env.get('RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD')
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was uploading the wrong apk, to another app's release.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the build.gradle.kts the following lines

```
android {
signingConfigs {
    getByName("debug") {
        storeFile = file(path your key)
        storePassword = password
        keyAlias = alias
        keyPassword = password
    }
}
```

}

This will also allow you to run the project in the emulator on another computer.

Answer (score -1):

if you don't want to see **Cannot invoke method readLine() on null object.** you need write in **gradle.properties** first.

```
KEYSTORE_PASS=*****
ALIAS_NAME=*****
ALIAS_PASS=*****
```

Answer (score -1):

If you, like me, just want to be able to run the release on your device for testing purposes, consider **creating a second keystore** for signing, so you can **simply put the passwords for it into your build.gradle** without worrying for your market key store security.

You can create a new keystore by clicking Build/Generate Signed APK/Create new...