# Signing apk by gradle - invalid encoding for special chars

Tags: android, encoding, gradle, android-studio, apk

According to many topics about configuring gradle to sign apk I used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020469/619673).
It seems it takes proper values, however I cannot success whole operation. Probably it could be a problem with letter "ł" which is even showing wrong in terminal. I need help, because I don't know what to do now. I've spent about 4 hours on it...

This is main project `app` gradle properites file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"    

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)

            storePassword RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS

            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS

            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    //...
}
```

This file takes data from `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file in Window's user dir.

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=false

    RELEASE_STORE_FILE=C:/users/xxx/f1/f1/android_market_key
    RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=lololo
    RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=łłłł
    RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=lololo
```

I've tried use:

```
compileOptions.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

or

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
}
```

or even adding to `gradlew.bat` some options for -D* to set encoding and still fail.

Please help, I stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out partially solution, every where where I needed to use special chars I used reading from console, and it finally worked:

Solution:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {


    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD

            def console = System.console()
            if (console != null) {
                keyAlias System.console().readLine("\n\$ Enter key alias: ")
            }

            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    //my dependencies
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of the `gradle.properties` file and make sure it's UTF-8.

Some editors (such as Notepad) default to ANSI encoding, that will cause problems in case if the file contains non-ASCII characters.

(Example: In Notepad: File -> Save As -> Encoding)

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue and spending some hours on it, I managed to make a successful build as follows:

1. Followed the instructions described [here](https://gist.github.com/gabrielemariotti/6856974). So, instead of using gradle.properties to store the values, I stored them in a custom file signing.properties.
2. Changed the file reading part as follows:

   props.load( new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(propFile), "UTF-8"))

I hope it helps.