# Can not Generate Signed .apk Using Android Studio

Tags: android

I am trying to export a Signed APK to submit to the play store but when I click Build->Generate Signed APK that option is grayed out and I can not select it.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but as a workaround you could use gradle build tasks.

I generally do all this from the command line. If you don't have any build flavors, try doing the following:

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

You can see multiple ways to sign your build using this process here: [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Comment: I see in windows I run gradlew assembleRease from the project root but I don't have a bat file there

Comment: Gradlew is the gradle wrapper. It usually lives in your root directory.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried checking your project structure has an Android facet?  Look under

**File** > **Project Structure** > Project Settings > **Facets**

This was missing for my project and prevented it from building.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronising the project seemed to have solved the issue for me:

**File > Synchronize**

Answer (score 0):

I am finding in the latest versions of Android Studio the **File > Project Structure > Project Settings > Facets** path does not exist.

To reach Facets do this:

On your Project tree click on the upper most element, the Project itself.  Then right mouse to expose the menu item **Open Module Settings**.

There you will find:

[Project Structure Window with Facets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csoTH.jpg)

Once you are there then I was successful in enabling the "Generate Signed APK" Build Menu item by adding the facets as shown below:

[Facets that worked for me building a Flutter app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQg86.png)

My apologies for the external links to the images, I don't have enough reputation points yet.