# "Generate Signed Apk" is not showing in Android Studio..Why?

Tags: android, android-studio

Hi im unable to generate APK.. "Generate Signed Apk" is not showing in Android Studio..Also when i click  "  Build APK(s) " nothing coming... check screenshot
Thanks

[image: Check Screenshot]

Comment: you can use CMD also to create signed apk. https://www.timroes.de/2013/09/22/handling-signing-configs-with-gradle/

Comment: Thanks.. but what happen? check this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF9xN.png

Comment: May be android studio has problem. You can create new android project and copy all this code to new project. Wish that works

Comment: Try `File - Invalidate and Restart`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not Generate Signed .apk Using Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749019/can-not-generate-signed-apk-using-android-studio)

Comment: Check my answer in the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64004696/11317944

Comment: You may want to check my answer that fixed my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64004696/11317944

Comment: [link to my response on similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64004696/11317944)

Answer (score 4):

Follow Below Steps for Nice and Easy Way:-

Go to Tools->Flutter->Open for editing in android studio.

Choose separate window. This will open the android part of your project in separate window.

Wait to Gradle to finish it's build.

Go to Build-> Generate signed bundle/apk.

Follow below video for further process.

https://youtu.be/MjpaSGEmQHs

Thank me later..!

Answer (score 3):

This happens if your android project did not synced successfully. You need to close your project and import it again, wait for notices for a possible needed update ie: SDK, sdk tools etc. and continue till it says synced successfully. After that the menu for generate signed apk will now be available.

Comment: not worked. I tried the same

Answer (score 2):

Probably your project is not an Android Application project but just an **Android Library** project.

Inside your **`build.gradle`** under your `app/` directory, there have to be a line as below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Double check this.

Comment: this one is the "top level" build script, you need to check the one inside "module level".

Comment: From your "top level" build.gradle, you are missing google() repo which should be put above jcenter().

Comment: Yes there is apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

Comment: Your project need to sync success firstly. From your screenshot, it synced failed. Check your sync error message details and fix that first.

Comment: 1:07 PM Gradle sync started

1:07 PM Project setup started

1:07 PM Gradle sync finished in 2s 872ms

Comment: i checked from another my app project.. its working well.. why this problem happen to this project ?

Answer (score 1):

I go the same problem and tried all the things. Here is what you need to understand before generating the release version.

1. Make sure that you have run `flutter clean` before procceding for this
2. Make sure you have generated the release sha keys for your application. If not then you can run the command from cmd to get it.
   or other way is.
   Open `Android studio` -> `open android folder as a project` -> right click on android folder -> `open module settings` -> `signing configs` -> `add new` -> named it something e.g. release -> create a new keystore from there -> add password an all other things required.
   once done add that keystore there save and apply.
   if you see successful message then proceed with the build

now you can click on build apk. it will build a signed apk

Answer (score 0):

I believe, it happens because of configuration. Check from the android studio console.

Check out this video: [Problem solved](https://youtu.be/TO7bmrLkWsQ)

Comment: but there is no configuration in my Event Log :(  how i select in manually

Comment: No..i just checked

Comment: youtube says "Video Unavailable"

Answer (score 0):

Open `Build.gradle` and check if lintOptions is **True** then change to **False**
 if not generate then add plugin

```
lintOptions {
       checkReleaseBuilds false
   }

//At the end of Build.gradle file
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to refresh your project, import the libraries again and see whether the build option is there or not.
Also check your project sdk.