# Option to "build signed apk" missing

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

After updating my Android Studio to the latest version, I can no longer find the option to build signed apk.

[image: Image to show options available currently]

I have tried installing beta and canary builds of Android Studio but they do not seem to carry the option either. Can someone help me figure out how to generate signed apks?

Comment: `./gradlew assembleRelease` https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by deleting and re-downloading **Android SDK Build-Tools**. Posting this here in case anyone else is facing this issue.

Comment: I noticed a message from Android Studio says: "Some **Android SDK Build-Tools** are missing". After downloading them, the option appeared now. Thanks for shifting my attention to this part!

Answer (score 12):

I've tried re-installing Android SDK Build Tools but that didn't work for me. But I managed to see the option by ensuring that the project is opened in the Android directory instead of the project root.

Comment: THANK YOU! This made the additional options show up for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try Invalidate restart
Goto File > Invalidate Caches/Restart 
If you still face the problem then you have to reinstall the android studio not the build.
Delete the android studio folder from users or where you have given the path while installing.then open the android studio and it will automatically start installing

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix is go to File->project Structure->build variants,in build types choose the build you want Debug or Release,scroll down and add a key to Manifest Placeholders apply the changes and click OK,i hope you'll find Generate signed bundle/APK options under build,i don't know if it's the right way to do,it's a rough guess.

Comment: I cannot find build variants option under file->project structure

Comment: sorry,I assumed you're on Android studio 3.4 canary 3.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution worked for me.
After lot of research, I found this reference. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.
Here as mentioned, we need to specify android build tool version in app\build.gradle file.

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially had problem with node on my project so I added this on terminal:

```
sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /usr/local/bin/node
```

Then on **File** > **Sync Project with Gradle File System**.

After this it showed on the Build menu.

Maybe, after this you can also do:  **File** > **Invalidate Chaches / Restart...**.

Answer (score 1):

Just open your project in Android Studio and click where shown below.
After that, the option will become available.

[image]

Comment: This option not showing to me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in build.gradle, verify if you have specify :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to connect a testing device or create a new virtual device (if you actually have not).

Answer (score 0):

My problem was also around the **Android SDK Build-Tools**, but the reinstall was not solving the issue.
I had to look at the logfile and find out, that I was using a platform version which wasn't installed. When I selected the particular verision in the SDK installer, everything started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, open your project directly on android folder
[image]