# Is using the Android Studio IDE the only you can build a signed APK using Capacitor 3?

Tags: android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

I recently migrated to Capacitor 3, and it appears that a few things have changed in terms of generated an APK with Ionic/Capacitor. Previously you were able to use the CLI to sign and build your release version of the APK, but now it appears that you need to use the Android Studio IDE to do so.

I am unable to figure out how to build my app within Android Studio.

It does not appear that I have any options available under my Build menu once the IDE launches after running the build command. I can see all of my files in the IDE, but I am unsure of what to do next.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to begin when trying to use Android Studio for the first time for a production build?

Can you still use the previous CLI commands to sign your app?

**Edit**

Here is a screen shot of my Build menu from Android Studio:

[image]

SDK Platforms:

[image]

SDK Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Build -> Generate Signed Bundle/APK[image: GenerateSignedApk] and follow the steps. You can provide the previous key that you used for signing. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing)

Comment: thanks for the reply! I think that's my main issue. Under my Build menu, there is no option to Generate Signed Bundle/APK. I added a screen shot to my original post.

Comment: I think some of your Android SDK Build Tools are missing. Try deleting and reinstalling Android Studio. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249990/option-to-build-signed-apk-missing

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I may have inadvertently removed some of the necessary build tools when I was cleaning up my computer looking for some extra space. Let me see what SDKs are installed.

Comment: I have updated the original post to include my SDK Platform and SDK Tools set-up. Do you happen to see anything that looks incorrect?

Comment: You can update the sdk tools (click on the checkbox where you see a "-" and make it a checkmark ☑️). See if that helps...other than that it looks fine to me

Comment: You also need to specify the build tools version in your  build gradle

Comment: It looks like that may be specified correctly: ```dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }```

Comment: I just noticed that if I run `gradle -v` it returns `4.10.2`, however in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` it's using `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0-all.zip`. Do I need to update gradle on my machine?