# android build release apk on jenkins, without storing my password in plain text

Tags: android, jenkins, apk, android-build

I need to be able to build the release version of my apk, using a Jenkins job.

From reading the following SO question

[How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle?rq=1)

I understand I can do it in one of two ways. Either get the user to enter the password at cmd prompt, or store my password details in a plain text file that doesn't get committed to git, and lives on my local machine.

Neither of these will work when running the build job on jenkins though. 1) I can't gain user input because this may be running in the middle of the night (I don't even know how to get user input from the cmd line even if the user was at their machine) 2) Anyone who can gain access to that build box, would be able to cat the contents of that file either via the cmd line or from another build.gradle job running on that jenkins server.

Does anyone know of anyway I can keep my password hidden but so that the Jenkins job can access it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Mask Password Plugin, which does just that. Or the same functionality is included in EnvInject plugin, and sooner or later all Jenkins projects get a need for EnvInject plugin (that does many other things), so might as well start using it now.

### To securely use a password from within a build/post-build step

- Install [**EnvInject plugin**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin).
- Under **Jenkins Global Configuration**, find **Global Passwords** section.
- Add a **name** (this will be the environment variable name) and **password** (will be starred **** ).
- Under **Job Configuration**, find **Build Environment** section.
- Checkmark **Inject passwords to the build as environment variables**.
- Then checkmark **Global passwords**.

In any build step, you can now use `$name` (as defined earlier) to refer to a password as you would if you were typing it in plain text.

- The password variable is injected only at job execution time (typing `$name` on command line of the server by itself will not produce anything, and like all Jenkins variables, it is not persistent).
- The job console log will show `****` instead of password, if it appears.
- You could configure passwords per job, rather than globally, so that other jobs can't use it.

The only security concern is that if someone has **administrative permissions to configure your job**, they can write `echo $name > secretpassword.txt` into a build step, and then review the file in the workspace. But you should be careful who you assign administrative rights to.

Comment: Wow, thanks. A great answer and something that we had hoped was available but couldn't find it

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look for this plugin

> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You both have the same response but @slav has more detail so i have the tick to him

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins instance happens to be running on EC2, and you don't want to permanently store secrets in the file system, you can put the store and key passwords into [Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html), then query them at build time. In addition, you can put the keystore itself into external storage, such as S3, and only keep it locally for the duration of the build.

Here is a sample build script (assume that the secret parameters are named `android-keystore-pass` and `android-signature-key-pass`):

```
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

keystore_file=keystore.properties
keystore=wise.jks

aws s3 cp s3://path-to-android/$keystore .

chmod go-rwx $keystore

touch $keystore_file
chmod go-rwx $keystore_file

cat > $keystore_file << EOF
storePassword=`aws ssm get-parameters --names android-keystore-pass --with-decryption | cut -f4`
keyPassword=`aws ssm get-parameters --names android-signature-key-pass --with-decryption | cut -f4`
keyAlias=android
storeFile=$WORKSPACE/$keystore
EOF
```

An example of the Gradle build scripts can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43230396/843660). You can commit a dummy `keystore.properties` to source control so that (non-release) builds work on dev machines.

There are also open-source secret distribution tools that are platform-independent, e.g. [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/), but I haven't tried any of them.