# How to zipalign apk file on windows 8.1

Tags: android, android-studio, zipalign

Yes i searched google and other questions

I don't see any zipalign etc in my sdk tools directory

Using latest android studio on windows 8.1 64 bit

I also tried build gradle but it also does nothing at output apk file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.monstermmorpg.pokemon"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

So how do i zipalign my output apk to publish at google store

Here screenshot

[image]

Comment: Use `Gradle`. Why are you trying to do it yourself? Post your entire `build.gradle`.

Comment: "I don't see any zipalign etc in my sdk tools directory" -- it is in your `build-tools/` directories, for each set of SDK build tools that you have downloaded through SDK Manager. "how do i zipalign my output apk" -- do a release build through Gradle, as `zipAlignEnabled` should already be `true`. Please explain what "it also does nothing at output apk file" means.

Comment: @JaredBurrows i definitely prefer that option updated question as you said ty very much waiting your answers

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG As I thought, you do not have a `signingConfig`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i choose build > generate signed apk from android studio and it generates an apk file named as "app-release-unaligned.apk" in "\app\build\outputs\apk\" folder and that file gives error of not zipaligned

Comment: @JaredBurrows ty for answer ho do i make sigingconfig ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should `zip align` and `sign` your `APK` with `Android Studio`.**

With this corrected `build.gradle` you will be able to run `gradlew assembleRelease`.

Generate your `keystore` with `Android Studio` like this:

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio

Your `build.gradle` should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.monstermmorpg.pokemon"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    signingConfigs { // <-- Signing Config you needed 
        release {
            storeFile file("other.keystore")
            storePassword "android"
            keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
            keyPassword "android"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release // <-- applied signing config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Read more here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system and http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Ty for answer however app is signed but not zipaligned :D

Comment: I am installing sdk never installed previously that can be error reason

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Do it with Android Studio. It will sign and zip align your apk. You seemed to break up your steps and still need help :D.

Comment: ok i found the error. it was that i was using incorrect file :D it generates app-release.apk and it works ty for help