# Android Studio: How can I get the aligned signed release APK?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

I'm using Android Studio, and for other projects, when I try to Generate a signed APK I get the `app-release.apk` file with any further trouble.

But in this particular project, I can only get an `app-release-unaligned.apk` file.

The main difference with my other projects is the use of the transloadit jar and org.apache.httpcomponents library for which I had to write down the packagingOptions field in my graddle file.

This is my build.grade file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bambinotes.bambinotessnap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            zipAlignEnabled true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENCE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
    compile files('libs/transloadit-1.0.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.anupcowkur:reservoir:2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
}
```

** UPDATE**

I've just found out what was the error that I was having, Android Studio was opening the finder in another folder, the one that generates the app-debug and app-release-unaligned files (which we can consider as intermediate files), the app-release.apk file was two folders up in the directory structure.

Even though I feel embarrassed for knowing the reason of my trouble, I'll leave this question open to see if this happens to anyone else in the future.

Comment: You can change the destination directory for the signed release build, to be the same as where the debug builds go.  That way they will show up where you would normally expect to look for them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The app-release.apk file is in the application folder.

Sometimes Android studio shows another directory where the unaligned file is, so you just have to look for the newly created file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the signing configuration to your Gradle file, see this answer for more information [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18329835/1333516)