# Gradle build task installRelease missing in Android project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Gradle seems to have lost a build type in a project I am working on. I can recreate a minimal problem as follows. I have the following files:

```
build.gradle
local.properties
src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 1
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {

        }
        release {

        }
    }
}
```

local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=/path/to/android-sdk-linux
```

src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="example"/>
```

I would expect Gradle to generate tasks `installDebug` and `installRelease`, since I define `debug` and `release` as `buildTypes`. However, this isn't the case. The command `gradle tasks` produces:

```
:tasks

------------------------------------------------------------
All tasks runnable from root project
------------------------------------------------------------

...

Install tasks
-------------
installDebug - Installs the Debug build.
installDebugAndroidTest - Installs the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallAll - Uninstall all applications.
uninstallDebug - Uninstalls the Debug build.
uninstallDebugAndroidTest - Uninstalls the android (on device) tests for the Debug build.
uninstallRelease - Uninstalls the Release build.

Verification tasks
------------------
...
```

What is going wrong? Why isn't task `installRelease` available?

Comment: Don't use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'.
The gradle plugin changes and in this way you are going to have issues with your build script.

Comment: Doesn't the + always use the latest gradle plugin? This is why I used it. It sounds like I'm wrong. (It looks like com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0 is "right" for now.)

Comment: Is it advisable to use + in dependencies?

Comment: Using the latest version doesn't mean to use the best version. A good pratice is to have a replicable build. If you are using "+" you will not be able to replicate the same build in the future. Same for dependencies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For release first you need to create `keystore` in root project.
And you need to provide those details in build.gradle.

You can create two `signingConfigs` debug & release both if you want.

At last in `buildTypes` link to that.

```
android {
        signingConfigs {
        debug {
          keyAlias 'alias'
          keyPassword 'password'
          storeFile file('../xyz.jks')
          storePassword 'password'
        }
      }
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 1
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }

        buildTypes {
            debug {
              signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
            release {
             signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            }
        }
```

Then `installRelease` will be also available in `gradle` Task

Hope this be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you! That works. The answer can be simplified slightly: you can drop `signingConfig signingConfigs.debug` from `buildType.debug`. (Renaming `signingConfigs.debug` to `signingConfigs.release` probably makes sense too.)

Comment: @user2768 glad to help you. I created only debug signingConfigs  so i used same for release also just to show you.

Comment: isn't it better to use the default `signingConfigs.debug`, since this will contain the debug signing key?

Answer (score 1):

For an edge case when you are not going to publish the app(testing of an obfuscated apk for example) you may skip signing with production key and do even simpler:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
    debug {}
  }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
          signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
         signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to generate a signing report to check if there is a build variant you expect and that it has a signing config you expect.

```
./gradlew app:signingReport
```

In my case it turns out I got this error because I was trying to run a different variant than I actually intended and I realized it when looking at this report