# How to get Signed SHA1 Fingerprint in Android Studio for Relase Mode?

Tags: android

I am having trouble to export SHA1 fingerprint for Release an application.Can anyone please tell me the details of how to get SHA1 fingerprint for releasing a signed application?

Comment: Duplicate Question---------http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle,,,,,,,,,,,http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the SHA1 fingerprint certificate in android studio for debug mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609442/how-to-get-the-sha1-fingerprint-certificate-in-android-studio-for-debug-mode)

Comment: no it's not duplicate... @Mayank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through command goto your java directory , below is the directory structure

```
.../jvm/jdk1.7.0/bin
```

After that type the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/hb/Documents/Testing.jks -alias testing -storepass testing -keypass testing
```

here Testing.jks is the project keystore, alias,storepass,keypass which you have given at the time of generating keystore.