# Execute .bat from Android gradle after APK build

Tags: android, batch-file, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I`m moving my project to **Gradle** build system. After **APK** build I need to sign it with manufacturer certificate.

How to execute .bat file by Gradle after APK was built?

```
task runSign(type:Exec) {
    println "Sign apk..."
    commandLine = ['cmd','/c','sign.bat']
}
```

I know just how to run .bat before build (but I need after):

```
preBuild.doLast {
    runSign.execute()
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `signingConfigs`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle

Comment: @Floern I use custom certificate from manufacture, that is not usual debug/release sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

Go to Run -> Edit Configurations...

Choose module where you want to run task after APK build. Add new configuration **after** "Gradle-aware Make".

[image: Picture 1]

Click on icon at picture below to choose module where task is implemented and write name of it.

[image: Picture 2]

After this steps your custom Gradle task will be executed after APK build.

Comment: how to execute batch file after APK is generated at this location "\app\build\outputs\apk" ? My requirement is like once xyz.apk generated at "\app\build\outputs\apk" location I want to move this file to "D:/Xyz" location automatically.

Comment: @KushPatel your batch file should be located in root of your module and be like: xcopy build\outputs\apk d:\Xyz (there is xcopy command on Windows platform)

Comment: i want to execute batch file from gradle after apk is generated in gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to perform something similar, but additionally to that I needed to know with which product favour was built, and with what configuration.

I've ended up adding following line into build.gradle:

```
android {
    applicationVariants.all { variant -> variant.assemble.doLast { signAndInstall.execute() } }
    ...
```

And with following helper function:

```
//
//  Returns array for CommandLine, path, variant (arm7), configuration (debug / release)
//
def getCommandLine(path)
{
    String taskReqStr = getGradle().getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(assemble|generate)(\\w+)(Release|Debug)")
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(taskReqStr)
    if (!matcher.find())
        return [ path ]

    String flavor = matcher.group(2).toLowerCase() + " " + matcher.group(3).toLowerCase()
    return [ path, matcher.group(2).toLowerCase(), matcher.group(3).toLowerCase() ]
}

task signAndInstall(type: Exec) {
    def batch = projectDir.toString() + '\\postbuild.bat'
    commandLine = getCommandLine(batch)
}
```

With following `postbuild.bat`:

```
@echo off
rem echo %0 %*
if %1. == . exit /b 0
if %2. == . exit /b 0
set InPath=%~dp0build\outputs\apk\%1\%2\app-%1-%2.apk
set OutPath=%~dp0build\outputs\apk\app-%1-%2.apk
copy /y %InPath% %OutPath% 1>NUL
```

You can of course configure this batch to perform anything what you like, %1 receives your product favour (e.g. `arm7, arm8, fat`...), and %2 receives `'debug' or 'release'` as configuration.

Comment: I got the error `Could not find method execute() for arguments [] on task` so I changed `execute()` to `exec()`