# Android Studio change SHA1

Tags: android, android-studio, sha1

I am using the last version of the Android Studio, but when I try to send the app for PlayStore I can't because the SHA1 is different.

This is SHA1 from the certificate:

[image: certificate]

but the app build has this SHA1:
[image: from apk]

---

I find a problem in Android Studio with my KeyStore.
The Key store has a SHA1 but the app with this keystore has another.

Just try this:

$ keytool -list -v -keystore mycert.keystore
will show:
SHA1: 67:F0:AE:82:85:7C:BD:C8:A0:CE:45:FA:6B:A5:92:E5:4A:34:40:AD

but when you build in Android Studio a app with this keyStore you will receive that:
$keytool -list -printcert -jarfile app-release.apk 
will show:
SHA1: 15:C3:B6:FB:B0:9B:21:DC:85:D6:04:FA:62:44:EA:F7:3D:85:FD:F8

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? What exact steps are you taking? What do you expect to happen? What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: It appears that you are signing the APK with a different certificate than it was originally signed with. You need to sign it with the exact same certificate in order to release an update.

Comment: I using the same certificate, but the original certificate don't have key pass.
And Android Studio force me to put the keypass, so I use the keystore in place.


This could make chance de SHA1 ?

If you wish try, I can send the SHA1 key store to you check the SHA1 from de certificate and the sha1 from the apk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to provide a keystore having that sha1 key while signing the apk [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18328730/4032259)

Comment: I do that 
but the result have another SHA1 key.
Some how the SHA1 change in the process.

Comment: I can provide the keystore if you want to try.

Comment: @user2013449 Giving the keystore to someone else is a bad idea. It will allow someone else to create apps that appear to be from you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes other apps change your keystore number - e.g. Unity does that.
Its not illegal, its just Unity thinks your keystore belongs to itself and writes over the SHA1 number.

Solution: store your keystore safely in an email or something.