# How to build a release test apk for Android with Gradle?

Tags: android, testing, gradle

I know, with the Gradle command `assembleAndroidTest` I can build a test APK. 
But I can use this test APK only for debug builds of my app, right? If I use it with a release build, I get error messages like `"[SDR.handleImages] Unable to find test for com.xxx.xxx (packagename)"`

How can I build a test APK in release mode with Gradle?

Comment: have u tried changing build varient? did you make realse buil varient?

Comment: I use Jenkins for building both, the app apk and the test apk. I have no build variants. I use `assembleRelease` for building the app apk and `assembleAndroidTest` to build the test apk. Then I use the Spoon runner to execute the tests on a device. But this only works, when using a debug app apk. If the app apk is a release build, executing the tests does not work.

Comment: I am having exactly the same issue, have you managed to solve this?

Comment: Why would you want to have test APK?

Comment: @blackHawk Firebase Test Lab for Android at Google Play allows to launch Android instrumentation tests on physical and virtual devices. But it requires both "App apk" and "Test apk" to be signed by the same release keys.

Comment: Yes I am having the same issue as well, have you managed to resolve this yet?

Comment: Are you looking at testing your application against different end points [server] for develop environment vs actual production environment? If not, then why can't you use debug version of both Application/Test APK?

Comment: Why don't you use different flavors? You will then get different gradle tasks to assemble the apk you want.

Comment: check this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle

Answer (score 12):

Add this line to your `defaultConfig`.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')
     }
}
```

Now you can run below command to get the release version of test apk

```
./gradlew assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=release
```

Comment: WoW, Simply amazing. I didn't know we could use System.getProperty here. I had to use a variable in gradle properties but then it couldn't change it in differnet gradle commands.

Comment: wow working, god bless you would be live 100 years

Answer (score 9):

To build a release test apk from gradle first you need to add followin test config in your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    ..
    ..
    buildTypes {
      release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testProguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-test-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      }
    }
    testBuildType "release"
}
```

After this you will start to see the `assembleReleaseAndroidTest` command. Through which you can run tests on release build.

In the process you may also need to create a `proguard-test-rules.pro` file, for test proguard rules

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
if (project.hasProperty('androidTestRelease')) {
        testBuildType 'release'
    }else {
        testBuildType 'debug'
    }
```

and to run tests in release build just add

```
-PandroidTest
```

to your command

Answer (score -3):

You can Create a Flavor to achieve this.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?