# Android studio- adding signing configurations to gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, code-signing, android-install-apk

I am very new to the android world and I was trying to just get to run a simple hello world app on my phone.
when I tried this I learnt that the APK generated by an android studio is an unsigned one. So to sign this I have gone through the process of creating a Key store and then a private Key, its alias and I was successful in signing the APK and installing on my phone and running it too.

Then I went through [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) for adding signing configurations to the gradle to automatically sign the release with the newly created key store file.
I have followed the steps n the above link properly and did not miss anything but still when I finish my signing configurations I have an error saying

> Gradle project sync failed.Basic functionality(eg. editing, debugging)
>   will not work properly.
>
> Error:(19, 0) Could not find property 'config' on SigningConfig
>   container.

I was taken by a surprise! and now I am not able to sign my APKs manually too. 
Now when I try to sign manually, it says the gradle is **not in sync**

I guess this file will be of help to help me solve this error. build.gradle of the project. I am trying to understand is what is mentioned here is same as the one I configured through the Android Studio UI while making the signing configurations.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("<path>\\firstKeystore.jks")
            storePassword "******"
            keyAlias "usual password"
            keyPassword "******"
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.tech.vasanth.newsfeed'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            debuggable false
            jniDebugBuild false
            renderscriptDebugBuild false
            zipAlign true
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a mistake in the `buildTypes.release` block. The signing config should be:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Note, that this is how you named the configuration in the `signingConfigs` block above.

Also leave out the signing config in the `buildTypes.debug` block (or, if you really want to have it, set it like above).

Comment: i have made changes like you have suggested and now i get the error at this line in buildTypes.debug signingConfig signingConfigs.config
can i remove this?

Comment: oh yeah.. thank you, it worked !
one thing what i want to know is, i have given a link above right? in that i used the studio's UI to configure the signing configurations. so instead i can do it by configuring the build.gradle also? both are one and the same?

Comment: Yes, the `build.gradle` file has all the information about the build. You can even build your project from the command line without opening Android Studio.

Comment: Wow that is nice to know, any pointers where i can play with the command line tools for building will be appreciated :)

Comment: Just cd to the root directory of your project and execute `gradlew build` (use ./gradlew if you are on Linux). All the details can be found in the gradle documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: Also I found a slight quirk, that you need to use `Build>Build APK` rather than `Build>Generate Signed APK Bundle` if you do the gradle script way of assigning the signing config. The latter option doesn't seem to work in this case

Answer (score 10):

I have been using below configurations for Debug/Release.

```
signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias 'keyAlias'
                keyPassword 'keyPassword'
                storePassword 'storePassword'
                storeFile file("${rootDir}/keystores/app.keystore")
            }

            debug {
                storeFile file("${rootDir}/keystores/debug.keystore")
                keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                keyPassword 'android'
                storePassword 'android'
            }
        }
```

While defining a release module:

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'other-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Here `rootDir` is your project root directory. Please store your keystore in mentioned directory.

Answer (score 4):

structure of get a release is like this :

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("release.keystore")
        storePassword "******"
        keyAlias "******"
        keyPassword "******"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```