# Can I edit xml/java codes of my android app on Brackets Editor?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, adobe-brackets

I am new to Android app development. I have a source code and would like to modify some xml/java codes. Can I use the  Brackets editor for this? I don't want to use Android studio as it's a bit complicated for me.

Comment: You can use any editor you like to edit XML and Java files, but it would be up to you to compile your project from the command line. I recommend learning Android Studio if you're serious about developing an Android project, though. It isn't that hard to learn.

Comment: I just need to change some color codes and some titles in strings file. Nothing more.

Comment: Editing the files is not a problem. You can open the java/xml files in any IDE or text editor and make your changes. It becomes harder if you want to export and package it as an app, for which Android Studio would be the preferred tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to, you can edit source files in an editor of your choosing and build the app manually via terminal. Actually, this is how it's done on Continuous Integration systems.

Typically Android projects are using Gradle build system, and come with Gradle wrappers. After you are done editing, *you can just* invoke it to assemble the release APK signed with proper keys as discussed in [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020469/8121754) thread. Note that it would require you having downloaded Android SDK and configured your paths properly, which would be tricky for a beginner, yet completely automated in a proper IDE.

If you are unlucky, it could be an old Eclipse project, or using some less popular build system, like Ant.

As you are new to Android development, I think you should go the more simple route and just download Android Studio and import your project.