# Not able to sign in with linkedin in android studio in release apk?

Tags: android, linkedin-api, release

I just followed “https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk”  for integrating linked sdk in my app.
the steps that i have done in my app such as,

1. Download linkedin library for mobile
2. Import it in my app as library
3. Get Key hash code
4. Create a application inside linkedin developer console
5. Configured package name & Package hash

After then everything is working fine in my app. that means i am able to access profile details from linkedin(debuggable case). but the problem is i am not able to login when i build the released apk.

Added `release key` inside linkedin developer app. for mac i just used the below command to get release key in terminal,

```
keytool -exportcert -keystore MY_RELEASE_KEY_PATH -alias MY_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Here is my `Activity` code:

```
public void login(View view) {
        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .init(this, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthSuccess() {
                        APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
           apiHelper.getRequest(MainActivity.this, topCardUrl, new ApiListener() {
                @Override                         

                public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse s) {

                 Log.e(TAG, "Profile json" + s.getResponseDataAsJson());
                 Log.e(TAG, "Profile String" + s.getResponseDataAsString());

                   try {
                     Log.e(TAG, "Profile emailAddress" + s.getResponseDataAsJson().get("emailAddress").toString());
                     Log.e(TAG, "Profile formattedName" + s.getResponseDataAsJson().get("formattedName").toString());

                     txtFirstName.setText(s.getResponseDataAsJson().get("emailAddress").toString());
                     txtLastName.setText(s.getResponseDataAsJson().get("formattedName").toString()); 

                     Picasso.with(MainActivity.this).load(s.getResponseDataAsJson().getString("pictureUrl"))
                            .into(imgProfilePic);

                        }catch (Exception e){

                        }

              }

                @Override 

                public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
                            //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.response)).setText(error.toString());                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Profile failed " + error.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

                }


                    @Override
                    public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed " + error.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }, true);
    }

    private static Scope buildScope() {
        return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode,
                                    int resultCode, Intent data) {

        LISessionManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .onActivityResult(this,
                        requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Everytime i am getting the below error while click on `signin with linkedin`button in my app.

```
Error={
"errorCode": "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
    }
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. If you fixed this issue please share it with us

Answer (score 1):

Attach your keystore.jks file to your project (if you are working with android studio), follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22485097/7134908) and realted answers.

Then generate your  Key Hash by the giving code.

```
private void genertaeHashKey() {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Generating Hash Key");
        try
        {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.e("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("KeyHash:", "" + e);
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)

        {
            Log.e("KeyHash:", "" + e);
        }
    }
```

then register your Key Hash on the linkedin developer console.
It did work for me. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed Build Variants debug to release ?

Comment: Follow this step:
keytool -exportcert -keystore MY_RELEASE_KEY_PATH -alias MY_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64