# save keystore password in android studio 3

Tags: android, android-studio

in android studio 2 you can save key store password and key password but in android studio 3 you can just save key password and you have to write key store password every time you want to build apk is there a settings or way to save key store password in android studio 3?
I Know I can save the password in my build.gradle file but I don't want to password be saved on git.

Answer (score 3):

I am having the same issue. But you can add your signing configs this way so they won't be checked into version control:

Put this into `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE={path to your keystore}
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=*****
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Modify your build.gradle like this:

```
...    
signingConfigs {

   release {
       storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
       storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
   }
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
```

Source: [How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

Comment: thank you, elvis but I'm looking for a solution to higher security

Comment: This doesn't even work, generate signed APK still blanks out the password.

Comment: true. i lost track which version of android studio where this issue started but it does not show up in the dialog anymore.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-17190).

On Mac you can fix this by manually adding a Keychain Access entry:

[image]

Comment: Every time I struggle to find how to bring this dialog up in the Keychain app. Could you please extend your answer to cover that, too?