# Keystore password was incorrect

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, keystore, android-keystore

When I try to create signed bundle for my flutter app I get

```
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > Failed to read key key0 from store "/Users/username/keystores": keystore password was incorrect
```

I have the correct password and I know this because I wrote it down. My password has only numbers and basic letters. When I run

```
./gradlew signingReport
```

I get

```
Variant: release
Config: release
Store: /Users/myname/keystores
Alias: key0
Error: Failed to read key key0 from store "/Users/myname/keystores": keystore password was incorrect
```

This same failure happened when I tried to use the keystore for the first time but then I was able to fix it by cleaning the android project. But now the cleaning does not work anymore.

Here is my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myApplicationId"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Here is my local.properties

```
sdk.dir=/Users/myName/Library/Android/sdk
flutter.sdk=/users/myName/developer/flutter
flutter.buildMode=release
flutter.versionName=0.1.5
flutter.versionCode=6
```

I have tried:

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project
- Default passwords ("changeit", "android", "password", "")
- Removing build folder
- Reinstalling Flutter, Dart and Android studio

Comment: could you please add your app/gradle file

Comment: see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle

Comment: I added app/gradle. In my opinion the keystoreProperties values are correct because if they were incorrect it would create different exception.

Comment: could you please add local.properties

Comment: I added local.properties

Answer (score 0):

you point gradle to `key.properties`

> def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')

> keystore password was incorrect

From this seems like your password is wrong.

If key.properties file is missing it will throw errors.

In the same folder as local.properties, create a key.properties and enter you values.

eg

```
storePassword=mysecretpassword
keyPassword=mysecretpassword
keyAlias=mykeyalias (if not sure it might be key0)
storeFile=.pathtokeyfile/key.jks
```

Comment: key.properties file is not missing and it is in the same folder as local properties. keyAlias is key0 like the ./gradlew signingReport says.

Comment: your password is wrong `keystore password was incorrect`

Comment: I do not think it is. I wrote down the password and I have signed 3 app bundles with that password. I believe that something has happened to the keystore file.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue but what I did was to go to my home location file and delete the upload-keystore.jks file and everything worked fine