# how to remove debug version in flutter project

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-developers-console

I try to upload my flutter project , and I have a issue that when I put the app-release.aab file the google play console rejected it!

I try to upload app-release.aab file.
the error told me that `You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle file that was signed in debug mode for a reason. The APK file or Android App Bundle must be signed in release mode. Read information about signing files or packages`
click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSjIO.png) to show image

Comment: Can you show your app level build gradle `buildTypes`?

Comment: yes , look like this :
`
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

`

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21020469/13625293

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your android app, before you release it. You can read documentation below on link:
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

you can also try following command:

```
flutter build appbundle --build-name=1.0.1+1 --build-number=3
```